# Precendence in C++ if-statements

Tags: c++, standards, operator-precedence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Short Circuit Evaluation guaranteed In C++ as it is in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108467/is-short-circuit-evaluation-guaranteed-in-c-as-it-is-in-java)
>   [How does C++ handle &&? (Short-circuit evaluation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211961/how-does-c-handle-short-circuit-evaluation)

I have the following struct definition and a particular use case:

```
struct foo
{
   bool boo;
};

int main()
{
  foo* f = 0;
   .
   .
   .
  if ((f) && (f->boo)) // <--- point of contention
   return 0
  else
   return 1;
}
```

Does the standard guarantee that the first set of braces in the if-statement above will always be evaluated before the second?

If it doesn't what is the best what to rewrite the above bit of code?

Currently I have the following mess:

```
if (f)
{
   if (f->boo)
      return 0;
   else
      return 1;
}
else
   return 1;
```

Comment: Yes, that's the point of short-circuiting.

Comment: Please update the question so that the two code segments agree; the `main()` version returns 0 in the first case but the 2nd example returns 1 in the first case.

Comment: @KevinGrant: No need to update; the question has been closed as an exact duplicate, and answer is clear.

Comment: I want to mention two things: The first is mentioned in a link: If you overload `operator&&` or `operator||`, it will lose its short-circuit nature. The second is that `&` and `|` work, and are not short-circuited, if you desire non-short-circuited behaviour.

Comment: @chris: But `&` and `|`, when applied to integer operands are bitwise, not logical. I suppose you could cast each operand to `bool` if you want non-short-circuit logical "and" and "or" operators.

Comment: @KeithThompson, True, it should be within a boolean context.

Comment: @chris: Then again, how often do you *need* non-short-circuit behavior?

Comment: @KeithThompson, Very good point. Both of those points were small things that are helpful to remember, but not prominent at all.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's guaranteed -- and the parentheses are unnecessary.

Both `&&` and `||` are short-circuit operators; they evaluate the left operand, then evaluate the right operand only if it's needed to determine the result.

Answer (score 5):

It may be a matter of style but you could say:

```
return (f && f->boo);
```

...or to be slightly more explicit:

```
return ((f && f->boo) ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: You have the condition reversed.

Comment: I was following the 2nd code segment in the original question...looks like that actually disagrees with the `main()` version.