# Objective C Conditional Statement Evaluation

Tags: objective-c, ios, conditional-statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is short-circuiting boolean operators mandated in C/C++? And evaluation order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order)

While researching an iOS issue, I found the following answer: [How to tell if UIViewController's view is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777438/how-to-tell-if-uiviewcontrollers-view-is-visible/2777460#2777460)

The specifics of the answer are not important, but what IS important is that it basically says that if you have an conditional statement that looks like the following...

```
if(X && Y)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

If X is false, Y will never be evaluated.  Is this true?  Can it be certain that the compiler will not optimize it to be `if(Y && X)`?

Comment: The compiler will not optimize it to (Y && X) to answer that part of the question.

Comment: Not a duplicate as the language does matter here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If X is false, it will return false and won't evaluate Y. It's an optimization.

Comment: But not to be confused with a compiler optimisation. It is part of the C/C++ standard. And it is not true if `&&` is overloaded, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2108502/1187415.