# Can I rely on short-circuit evaluation to check vector bounds in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

Is the following code acceptable?

```
if(vector.size() > 0 && vector[0] == 3) {
}
```

Or is there a chance that it will crash when the vector is empty? I haven't noticed this happening, but I'm worried that it's still possible.

Comment: It's fine. As you said, short-circuit evaluation comes into play. You can alternatively use `!vector.empty()` for the first part, though.

Comment: Yes. Short-circuiting is defined precisely by the standard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Short Circuit Evaluation guaranteed In C++ as it is in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108467/is-short-circuit-evaluation-guaranteed-in-c-as-it-is-in-java)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that works, but it would be more idiomatic to say `!vector.empty() && vector[0] == 3`: That will work for all containers with maximal efficiency, so it's never worse, sometimes better and always more readable.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can rely on the builtin operator `&&` to short-circuit. That's part of its specification.

Comment: Upvote. Sidenote: This "two-step" with `operator &&` is one of the features of the language I dislike the most. Frankly, the committee should have *never* allowed overloading of && and || if they could not *guarantee* that the same semantics applied whether a built-in or an overloaded operator is being invoked.

Comment: Nik Bougalis like anything if it is ambiguous don't do it.  It's the same if I overload operator++ to decrement.