# Order of execution for an if with multiple conditionals

Tags: c

In an if statement with multiple conditionals, is the second conditional executed if the outcome of the first is clear?

example:

```
if(i>0 && array[i]==0){
}
```

If I swap the conditionals a segfault may occur for negative values of i, but this way no segfault occurs. Can I be sure that this always works or do have have to use nested if statements?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order

Answer (score 107, accepted):

This type of evaluation is called [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). 
Once the result is 100% clear, it does not continue evaluating.

This is actually a common programming technique.
For example, in C++ you will often see something like:

```
if (pX!=null && pX->predicate()) { bla bla bla }
```

If you changed the order of the conditions, you could be invoking a method on a null pointer and crashing. A similar example in C would use the field of a struct when you have a pointer to that struct.

You could do something similar with or:

```
if(px==null || pX->isEmpty()} { bla bla bla }
```

This is also one of the reasons that it is generally a good idea to avoid side effects in an if condition.

For example suppose you have:

```
if(x==4 && (++y>7) && z==9)
```

If `x` is `4`, then `y` will be incremented regardless of the value of `z` or `y`, but if `x` is not `4`, it will not be incremented at all.

Comment: +1. Worth mentioning, an exception to side effects in an if condition is checking for error return values: `if (function_that_returns_neg_on_error(param1, param2) < 0) { perror("function"); return -1;}`

Answer (score 47):

The operators `&&` and `||` guarantee that the left-hand side expression will be fully evaluated (and all side effects applied) before the right-hand side is evaluated. In other words, the operators introduce a sequence point.

Additionally, if the value of the expression can be determined from the lhs, the rhs is not evaluated.  In other words, if you have an expression like `x && y`, and x evaluates to 0 (false), then the value of the expression is false regardless of y, so y is not evaluated.

This means that expressions like `x++ && x++` are well-defined, since `&&` introduces a sequence point.

Answer (score 22):

From draft 3485 (n3485.pdf) Its clearly stated that

> ### 5.14 Logical AND operator [expr.log.and]
>
> ```
> logical-and-expression: 
>       inclusive-or-expression
>       logical-and-expression && inclusive-or-expression
> ```
>
> 1. The && operator groups **left-to-right**. The
>    operands are both contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). The
>    result is true if both operands are true and false otherwise. Unlike
>    &, **&& guarantees left-to-right evaluation**: the second operand is not
>    evaluated if the first operand is false.
> 2. The result is a bool. If the
>    second expression is evaluated, every value computation and side
>    effect associated with the first expression is sequenced before every
>    value computation and side effect associated with the second
>    expression.

Comment: what do you mean by unlike &? If i use & then the order is not guaranteed?

Comment: Ex: if((func1() & func2()) == true) vs if(func1() && func2())