# IF and order of comparisons

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I am working on a project and I keep finding lines like this one:

```
if(pointer && pointer->whatever) {...}
```

Is it safe to assume that the `if` will carry on comparisons in the same order as described in the source code? Or may it happen that `pointer->wathever` is evaluated before (or concurrently) to the check of `pointer` against NULL?

Comment: Yes, sorry I couldnt find it before posting

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21282873/376535)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is a safe statement. Conditionals `&&` and `||` are executed in [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) fashion in C.

If `pointer` is `NULL` then `pointer->whatever` will **not** be executed.

Comment: Can't say about `C` but for `C++` it holds only when `||` or `&&` used

Comment: @qwm I have changed it to those.But I actually can't think of other infix conditional operators in C...

Comment: I've never heard the term "conditional operator", and "conditional" on its own usually refers to anything which is, well, dependent on a condition, without making statements about the shape of the condition. The more common term for what you mean are boolean operators.

Comment: @delnan `?:` is called a conditional operator.

Comment: @Simple Right. Though that's a different meaning than in this answer and as stupid as I think it is, the term "ternary operator" is more common.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(pointer && pointer->whatever)
```

Is like writing:

```
if(pointer) {
   if(pointer->whateve) {

   }
}
```

So, yes. Read about Short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: I thought the compiler could potentially optimize the code in such a way that this would not hold true anymore

Comment: @user815129 the compiler and even CPU may reorder the statements as such far as there are no side effects. So it might calculate already the memory offset of pointer->whatever as that in itself gives no issue. However it should not access that memory until the first statement is true.

Comment: @user815129 Then this answer would be wrong, since the usual interpretation of "code A is equivalent to code B" takes optimizations, undefined behavior etc. into account. Fortunately, it's not wrong. Which is why I'm surprised about the downvotes.

Comment: So this is wrong? I don't understand....

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's not exactly the same but that was also not stated.

Comment: The answer is wrong because if there were an else statement it would not get executed.

Comment: @user815129 This is *defined* in the C and C++ language definitions. All textbooks on these languages explain about this...

Comment: @self. It'll be wrong as well if it was a potato. I answered the question as it is, no `else` there.

Answer (score 2):

The order of evaluation (for C and C++) of the `&&` operator is left-to-right. Hence pointer will always be tested before any following statements. Any following statements will not be evaluated if pointer is evaluated false (short-circuiting).

Answer (score 0):

Logical expressions are evaluated from `Left-to-right` and once the result became definitive it stops evaluating the other expressions. So if the expression `pointer` if `false`, `pointer->whatever` will not be evaluated. So it's abdolutly stafe to use it as you did.

Comment: You are mixing up associativity, order of evaluation and short circuiting. Being left associative only means that `f() && g() && h()` is interpreted as `(f() && g()) && h()`, with no guarantees about which function gets called first. Order of evaluation makes those guarantees about that. But left-to-right order of evaluation does not guarantee that the right operand is not evaluated if the left already determined the result. That's called short circuiting.