# Please explain an apparent conflict between precedence of && and || and the actual result of an expression

Tags: c

I don't understand the output of the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=-3, j=2, k=0, m;
    m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", i, j, k, m);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `-2 2 0 1` instead of `-2 3 1 1`, implying that `++i` was evaluated (and caused the `||` operator to short-circuit its right hand side) before the expression `++j && ++k` which appears to contradict the fact that the `&&` operator has higher precedence than `||`.

Would someone explain why?

Comment: m is integer type

I know the anwer... I need explaination

why is k=0

Comment: `j` and `k` are never incremented because that part of the expression is short-circuited.  `++i` is true, so the rest of the expression is not evaluated.

Comment: && has higher precedence,so why are j and k not incremented

Comment: I fixed up the question to reflect what OP was trying to ask (let's help him out here) and voted to reopen.

Comment: I tried to improve the question further to make the source of the OP's confusion clearer, and replaced the title. I would have voted to reopen too, but it happened before I finished my edit.

Comment: It probably does not matter since writing such code is a really dumb idea - simply because the operator and sequence point rules are so arcane.  It is 'smarter' (in terms of productivity) to avoid the dark corners than to waste time understanding them.

Comment: @Clifford: in this case, I can't agree. Just for example, it's fairly common to see code that checks for a non-null pointer, then dereferences it: `if (x && x->whatever) ...`, and to understand why it works, you *need* to understand what `&&` means.

Comment: @anurag:  Since `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, `a || b && c` is parsed as `a || (b && c)`.  The thing that may be confusing you is that `||` and `&&` short-circuit, so not all expressions need be evaluated.  In this case, `++i` has a value of -2, which is true, so nothing on the right-hand side of `||` will be executed.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: That was not what I was referring to, your example was clear and unambiguous and entirely legitimate and not at all like the expression used in this post.  The problem of arcane precedence and *sequence point* rules does not apply in your example.  The ill-advised usage I was referring to applies to the use of ++ and -- operators in an expression involving other operators.

Comment: Er... Marked it as duplicate and only later realized that it was asked earlier than what I suggested instead.

Comment: @AndreyT There is another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239286

Comment: @martin: Yes, this is one of the most popular questions, which pops up again and again with remarkably similar wording and code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression:

```
++i || ++j && ++k
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(++i) || ((++j) && (++k))
```

Explaining:

1. `++i` is evaluated -- `(-2) || ((++j) && (++k))`;
2. The `||` operator is evaluated -- `(1)`;

Since `1 || anything` evalutes true, the right operand is not evaluated. Thus, the `&&` precedence doesn't matter here. This short circuiting is guaranteed in both C and C++ by the relevant standards (see [Is short-circuiting logical operators mandated? And evaluation order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526)).

Now, try using a sub-expression, like this:

```
(++i || ++j) && ++k
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
((++i) || (++j)) && (++k)
```

Explaining:

1. `++i` is evaluated -- `((-2) || (++j)) && (++k)`;
2. `||` is evaluated -- `(1) && (++k)`
3. `++k` is evaluated -- `(1) && (1)`;
4. Evaluates true;

Answer (score 22):

The output should be something like:

```
Error, line 2: 'm': undefined variable.
```

Edit: with that fixed, only the `++i` should be evaluated. Precedence does not determine (or even affect) order of evaluation. Precedence means the expression is equivalent to `++i || (++j && ++k)`. Order of evaluation for `||` or `&&` is always that the left operand is evaluated, then there's a sequence point. After the sequence point, the right operand is evaluated if and only if necessary to determine the final result (i.e., the right operand of `||` is evaluated if the left operand evaluated to zero; the right operand of `&&` is evaluated if the left operand evaluated to non-zero).

In this expression, `++i` is evaluated, then because it's the left operand of `||` and evaluated non-zero, none of the rest of the expression is evaluated.

Comment: +1 for making me chuckle. I agree. :D

Comment: It was originally all one line, with the m being part of the declaration with the rest.  When breaking it up, the editor apparently split the lines, inserting the error.

Comment: @James - Even when it was a one liner there was a `;` between the k and the m.

Answer (score 3):

**-2 2 0 1**

Lazy.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

 int i=-3,j=2,k=0;
 int m=++i||++j&&++k;

 printf("%d %d %d %d",i,j,k,m);

}
```

Compile, run and see for youself.

```
gcc tmp.c -o tmp
```

Comment: Shouldnt && be executed first because of higher precedence?

Comment: No. This is very nicely explained in Jerry Coffin's answer. The OP and others just have an understanding problem.

Answer (score 0):

By way of explanation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    if (-1)
        printf ("-1!\n");
    else
        printf ("Not -1.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Negative numbers are not false in C. Always compare boolean values to 0 (or `FALSE`) or you can get bitten by `if (worked == TRUE)` giving false negatives.