# How do C++ operators work

Tags: c++, operators, operator-precedence

Given that x = 2, y = 1, and z = 0, what will the following statement display?

```
printf("answer = %d\n", (x || !y && z));
```

It was on a quiz and I got it wrong, I don't remember my professor covering this, someone enlighten me please... I know the answer I get is 1, but why?

Comment: "what will the following statement display?" Go run it yourself... yikes. If you then don't understand and want to ask "why?", *that's* a reasonable question.

Comment: i know, i did, but that doesnt explain to me the logic behind the operation :/

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375041

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does “++x || ++y && ++z” calculate “++x” first, even though operator “&&” has higher precedence than “||”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3700352/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression is interpreted as [`x || (!y &&z)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700352/why-x-y-z-calculate-x-firstly-however-operator-is-higher/)(check out the precedence of the operators `||`, `!` and `&&`.

`||` is a [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) operator. If the left operand is true (in case of `||`) the right side operand need not be evaluated.

In your case `x` is true, so being a boolean expression the result would be 1.

**EDIT**.

The order of evaluation of `&&` and `||` is guaranteed to be from left to right.

Comment: Would you care explaining "short-circuiting"?

Comment: short-circuit boolean evaluation means that if the left-hand side value is enough to determine the truth of the entire expression, then the right-hand values aren't evaluated at all.  This is both an optimisation, and essential when checking say a pointer is not null on the left, then dereferencing it on the right.  For || - the OR operator - if the left hand value is true then the entire expression is true, and the right-hand part unevaluated.

Comment: @Tony: whether or not the right-hand part is *evaluated* is irrelevant since it has no side-effects. What matters is that `&&` has higher precedence (i.e. binds more tightly) than `||`.

Comment: ohh ok that makes sense, thnx a lot!

Comment: @R : Yes you were right, I have edited my answer for more clarity.

Comment: @R: was just answering thrgle's general question... no claim of relevance to the expression in the question intended. BTW - playing devil's advocate - everyone's assuming x, y, z behave like builtin types: could have an operator=(X) for some numberic type X but a operator bool() const or similar that's not intuitive. Still, question is tagged C++ and C, so can ignore C++'s user-defined-type ability... :-)

Comment: So what should be the output of 'int main(){
        int x = 0, n = 0;
 
        bool b = ++x || (++n);
 
        cout << n;
}'

Comment: Since parenthesis has higher priority than any other operator involved in the expression, would n be 1?

Comment: @Chubsdad : Precedence has got nothing to do with the order of evaluation. `++x || (++n)` is similar to `++x || ++n` . The order of evaluation is well defined for operarors like `&&, || , comma `. 

`n` would still be 0 because evaluation of `++n` would not take place due to the short circuiting effect of `||`.

Comment: @Chubsdad : @R meant to say that if `||` had higher precedence then `(x || !y && z)` would have been interpreted as `( (x||!y) && z) )` which would have caused the evaluation of `z` because the first operand of `&&` would be non-zero. Since the expression had no side effects so whether the right hand side is evaluated is irrevant as @R said.

Comment: Oh Ok. That's what was bothering me. It's fine now

Comment: (Irrelevance is also arguable... short-circuit evaluation may take more or less CPU cycles, but that's not the expressed concern in the original question....)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, it will print 1. (Let's assume short circuiting is off)

`(x || !y && z)` or `(true || !true && false)` will first evaluate the ! operator giving `(true || false && false)`

Then the &&: `(true || false)`

Then || : `true`

Printf will interpret true in decimal as 1. So it will print `answer = 1\n`

Comment: The ! will not be evaluated first!  x will be.

Comment: Wrong - see Prasoon's answer and consider short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: Note I said assume no short circuiting. But otherwise you are correct. I thought he might want a more thorough answer.

Comment: if your compiler permits disabling short-circuiting, please, delete it.

Comment: @jweyrich: Indeed I would delete it. My intent was to illustrate the order of operations to a learning student.

Answer (score 0):

> Given that x = 2, y = 1, and z = 0,
> what will the following statement
> display?
>
> printf("answer = %d\n", (x || !y && z));

Ok - feeling a bit guilty for the harsh quip re poor wording of the question, so I'll try to help you in a different way to the other answers... :-)

When you've a question like this, *break it down* into manageable chunks.

Try:

```
int x = 2, y = 1, z = 0;

printf("true == %d\n", 10 > 2);                 // prints "1"
printf("false == %d\n", 1 == 2);                // prints "0"
printf("!y == %d\n", !y);                       // prints "0"
printf("(x || !y) == %d\n", x || !y);           // "1" - SEE COMMENTS BELOW
printf("(!y || z) == %d\n", !y || z);           // "0"
printf("(x || !y && z) == %d\n", x || !y && z); // "1"
```

In the output there, you've got everything you need to *deduce* what's happening:

- `true == 1` reveals how C/C++ convert truthful boolean expressions to the integral value 1 for printf, irrespective of the values appearing in the boolean expression
- `false == 0` reveals how C/C++ converts false expressions to "0"
- `(!y) == 0` because ! is the logical not operator, and C/C++ consider 0 to be the only integral value corresponding to false, while all others are true, so `!1 == !true == false == 0`
- `(x || !y) == 1`, and you know `!y` is 0, so substituting known values and simplifying: `(2 || 0) == 1` is equivalent to `(true or false) == true`... *that's understandable as a logical rule*
- `(!y || z) == 0` - substituting known values: `(0 || 0) == (false or false) == false == 0`
- `(x || !y && z) == 1`: here's the crunch!  From above, we know:

  - `x || !y` is 1/true, which if relevant would imply 1/true && z/0/false == 1/true <- this clearly doesn't make any sense, so it must not be the way C/C++ are calculating the answer!
  - (!y && z) is false, which if relevant would imply x/2/true || false == 1/true <- this is true, so it must be the implicit order.

In this way, we've derived the operator precedence - the order of evaluation of the || and && operators, from the results that the compiler is displaying, and seen that if and only if && is valuated before || then we can make some sense of the results.

Answer (score -1):

```
answer = 1
```

or maybe:

```
answer = -27
2 || !1 && 0
2 || 0 && 0
2 || 0
true
true = non-zero value
printf("answer = %d",*true*); -> who knows
```

Most compilers will output `answer = 1`.  I wouldn't confidently state that *all* compilers will do that though, but I am confident all compilers would return non-zero.

Comment: Wrong, short-circuiting is irrelevant. That's only a matter of whether side effects occur. This is a simple operator precedence problem. If you don't believe me, try replacing `&&` with `,` (the comma operator). :-)

Comment: No, the answer is always 1. The result of logical AND and OR is always an `int` with the value `0` or `1`. C++ is the same, except that the type is `bool`, which gets promoted to an `int` when passed to `printf`.

Comment: Now you're wrong for a new reason. The answer is always 1. Result of logical operators in C is well-defined as 0 or 1; it's not an implementation issue.

Comment: @R.: the question is tagged C and C++

Comment: @R C has a long history.  Much longer than C standards.  The first C compiler was out mid-70's, while the first C standard was around 89.  When working with a language who's implementation far preceeded the standard, it is ALWAYS a question of implementation.  The true <-> non-zero relationship is rampant in C.  Feel free to go test every C compiler ever written and prove none of them worked this way - short of that - no sale.  I will, however, update my post to change "C compliant" to indicate a possible return from compilers.

Comment: Why on earth no one downvotes this? How does true becomes a non-1 value? How isn't operator precedence relevant here?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not going to give you the outright answer because you could just compile it and run it, but the question is just testing to see if you know operator precedence.