# How does this boolean expression work

Tags: c

The output of the following program is not as i had expected it to be.Please explain it to me how the logical expression works in this program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=-3, j=2, k=0, m;
    m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k, m);
    return 0;
}
```

the output i had expected is -2, 3, 1, 1
the output is -2, 2, 0, 1
why are j and k not increamenting

Comment: I don't know C but my guess would be that `||` is a shortcircuiting operator and that `-2` evaluates to true when coerced into a boolean. That boolean true then becomes 1 when outputted as a number by the `printf`.

Comment: @Chris: That's correct (except that there's no coercion; `&&` and `||` yield a result of type `int` with value `0` or `1`).

Comment: this is an exact duplicate of [Please explain an apparent conflict between precedence of && and || and the actual result of an expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375041) and the short circuiting is explained in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526)

Answer (score 10):

since ++i is not zero, and hence true, the evaluation of the statement stops and returns true

ie

```
true || (++j && ++k)
```

is always true, and is true without needing to evaluate the bit after the || and hence it wont change j or k

Comment: Small addition: Some compiler options allow to not-shortcircuit, and result in the expected output. Check your specific compiler documentation.

Comment: there are C compilers that will not short circuit?! - I am very surprised. So much C code depends on this behavior. And humans reading the code would expect it too

Comment: @pm100 see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526), it is guaranteed

Comment: Should be noted, the purpose of the short-circuit is to save CPU cycles.

Comment: yes - it was, but it is now relied on every where . How often have you seen if(ptr != null && ptr->flag). Without short circuit that code fails

Answer (score 2):

`j` and `k` are not incrementing because of *short circuit* feature of `||`. Evaluation of `++i || ++j && ++k` stops right after `++i` is evaluated to be non-zero (meaning true).

Answer (score 2):

When you have a boolean expression, a part of it may be sufficient to get the result. For instance, `-2 || 3 && 1` is the same as `(-2) || (3&&1)`. So if `(-2)` yields `true`, the whole expression yields `true`, and there is no need to evaluate the rest of the expression. This way, `++j && ++k` never gets executed.

You might also want to try this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=-3, j=2, k=0, m;
    m = ++j && ++k || ++i;
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k, m);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am right (someone correct me if I'm wrong), it evaluates ++i (which returns a non-zero value), so ++i is "true", than the compiler sees ||, with a "true" expression preceding it, so it skips line and returns "true" (1). The program never execute ++j nor ++k.

Comment: Yes, you are right. See Wojitek Surowka's answer, that behavior is guaranteed by the C standard.