# good practice in c++ (lazy evaluation)

Tags: c++, lazy-evaluation

I have some question about lazy evaluation of c++, can I be sure that this snippet of the code will always work, or it is bad idea? if Yes, why? Thanks in advance

> if(currentNode == 0 || *currentNode ==
>   element){
>        return; }

Comment: It will always work, but it might still be a bad idea. :) More context is needed to evaluate the code.

Comment: @Karl: what do you think is bad about it.

Comment: It **might** be bad, *depending on context*, that `currentNode` is a pointer in the first place, or that it is allowed to be null, or that the logic works this way, or...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is short-circuiting boolean operators mandated in C/C++? And evaluation order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is guaranteed to work: logical AND and OR expression chains are evaluated from left to right, and if the first subexpression satisfies the condition, no further subexpressions are evaluated.

In your case, if `currentNode` is null, it will never get dereferenced by the second subexpression, so the code is safe.

As @jdv pointed out though, this is called *short-circuit evaluation*, not *lazy evaluation*. The latter is a programming technique where you, transparently to the client, calculate a required value only the first time when it is concretely needed. A simplistic example:

```
class Example {
  SomeClass *theObject = null;
public:
  SomeClass *getTheObject() {
    if (!theObject) {
      theObject = doResourceConsumingCalculation();
    }
    return theObject;
  }
};
```

Note that the client of `Example` is unaware of the implementation detail that `theObject` is evaluated lazily, so you are free to change back and forth between eager and lazy evaluation without affecting the public interface of the class.

(Of course, in real production code, `getTheObject` should be implemented in a separate cpp file, and it should probably include synchronization, error handling code etc. This is just a simplistic example :-)

Answer (score 13):

Yes this is safe. It is called short-circuit boolean evaluation.

For completenes it deserves mention that in principle it is possible to override the || and && operators. If you do so, this will break the short circuit evaluation, and is therefore not reccomended.

Answer (score 3):

For lazy-evaluation in a multi-threaded environment you should consider using boost::once to perform the one-time loading.

```
class Example
{
   mutable boost::once_flag flag;
   mutable SomeClass * theObject;

   void loadTheObject() const;

public:
   Example() :
      flag(BOOST_ONCE_INIT),
      theObject( NULL )
   {
   }

   SomeClass * getTheObject() const
   {
        boost::call_once( flag, boost::bind( &Example::loadTheObject, this ) );
        return theObject;
   }
};
```

Comment: Note: there is now a "once" construct in standard C++.
If there is a possibility that the value will not load, it is better that the method that loads does not "leak" an exception. It is therefore a good idea to have some kind of decorator in your cache that shows the failed state.