# Will the 2nd conditional in an OR ever be executed if the 1st conditional passes?

Tags: c, if-statement, crash, operators, conditional-statements

For example:

```
if(pos == -1 || character_array[pos] == 0) {

}
```

If pos is -1, can I count on this NEVER crashing?

Same goes with AND statements in which the first conditional fails.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613551/good-practice-in-c-lazy-evaluation

Comment: possible duplicate of [C : is there "lazy evaluation" when using && operator, as in C++ ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958864/c-is-there-lazy-evaluation-when-using-operator-as-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can count on this.  The relevant parts of the C standard are 6.5.13:

> Unlike the bitwise binary `&` operator, the `&&` operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the
>   evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand compares equal
>   to `0`, the second operand is not evaluated.

and 6.5.14:

> Unlike the bitwise `|` operator, the `||` operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the
>   evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand compares unequal
>   to `0`, the second operand is not evaluated.

For example, the following is idiomatic C:

```
if (foo && foo->bar > 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

C supports [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) with the logical `||` and `&&` operators, so in your case it should work as you describe, i.e. not crash.

Answer (score 3):

This is language specific, but most languages will ignore the rest of the statement if the first part is true for a `||`.

Similarly, most languages will ignore the rest of the statement if a part of a `&&` is false.

If you *want* everything to be executed, then use the single `|` and `&` operators instead.