# C++ exception handling, error

Tags: c++

I am using a library, RapidXML, but my problem is more general. The library parses xml like `item->first_node("CRAP")->first_node("CRAP")` Now, if I put this in an `if` statement it will crash. If I put this: `item->first_node("CRAP")` it won't.

I am a beginner in C++ and I don't know much about exceptions but:

```
try
{
    if(item->first_node("CRAP")->first_node("CRAP"))
    {

    }
    cout << "OK";
} catch (...)
{
    cout << "CRASH";
}
```

The above crashes. How to check if my node exists without crashes (and without looping all the items one by one)?

Comment: Always post full error messages (i.e. copy and paste the entire error message from start to finish) instead of using vague terms like "it crashes".

Comment: Sounds like it's returning a null pointer.

Comment: literally crashes, boom, no error.

Comment: @chris: I believe this is it, but how to check if a null pointer pointing to a null pointer is null?

Comment: You cannot have a null pointer pointing to a null pointer (that makes no sense). But to check if a pointer is null, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185821/so-how-do-we-check-if-a-pointer-is-null-pointer).

Comment: yes but this crashes again

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger.

Comment: What does this have to do with C++ exceptions? Does the library specify that `first_node` ever throws anything?

Comment: It throws this: http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#classrapidxml_1_1parse__error

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to take it one step at a time:

```
if (item != 0) // check if item is null
{
    rapidxml::xml_node<char>* node = item->first_node("CRAP"); // Try to grab first child node
    if (node != 0)
    {
        // okay got a valid node, grab next one
        rapidxml::xml_node<char>* next = node->first_node("CRAP");
        if (next != 0)
        {
           // Okay
        }
    }
}
```

When you try it in one step, i.e. `item->first_node("CRAP")->first_node("CRAP")`, you never check that the first call to `first_node` returned a null pointer (assuming `item` is a valid pointer also).

Comment: Assuming `item` is not NULL to begin with.

Comment: `auto` implies C++11, so you should compare against `nullptr` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like either `item` is NULL or `item->first_node("CRAP")` is returning NULL.  Try this, see what output you get:

```
try
{
    node *n; // <-- use whatever type first_node() actually returns

    if (!item)
        cout << "item is NULL";
    else
    {
        n = item->first_node("CRAP");
        if (!n)
            cout << "first node is NULL";
        else
        {
            n = n->first_node("CRAP");
            if (!n)
                cout << "second node is NULL";
            else
                cout << "OK";
        }
    }
}
catch (...)
{
    cout << "CRASH";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Always test whether an expression is `NULL` before using it as part of a longer expression. Never write things like

```
if(item->first_node("CRAP")->first_node("CRAP"))
```

if `first_node("CRAP")` can return `NULL`. Instead, write something like

```
if(item->first_node("CRAP") && item->first_node("CRAP")->first_node("CRAP"))
```

This works because the '&&' (logical and) operator uses *lazy evaluation*: it won't bother to evaluate its second operand if the first one evaluates to false.

Comment: Heh. Hard to type good answers on an iPhone, don't know why I even try.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill The backtick is available by holding down the quote key on the punctuation keyboard.

Comment: @RemyLebeau -- clarity is more important than performance, except when it's not. Oftentimes a single conditional expression is preferable to a couple of nested blocks, unless you're in a tight loop.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the reason this works is because of [lazy evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613551/good-practice-in-c-lazy-evaluation) (for those who might not be aware of it).

Comment: Yes but if I have 20 items (ITEMS1->ITEM2 etc), how to check it without making my code x100?

Comment: @Blazer That's a great question, and the answer really is that an API that returns `NULL` to mean "not found" is difficult to use this way. A nicer API could return a special "null object" that returned "false" or other null object values from all its methods. You can read about this idea here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern . An API designed this way is much more convenient to use with chained method calls.

Comment: @Blazer: Well, you can write a simple wrapper that observes Null Object Pattern as suggested.