# How to design this program with easy modification in mind?

Tags: c++

This question is about how to design a program so it will be easy to make certain modifications.

I have a class which holds some (non-trivial) data and has several member functions that change this data.

Sometimes I need to compute some property of this data.  But it is slow to recompute it from scratch on every change.  It is much faster to compute a small update to these properties instead.

I have several such properties which I need to be able to easily add or remove to/from my class (or turn on/off) to carry out some numerical experiments.  The class is only modified by myself and is used for numerical simulations (scientific code).

#### Concrete example

Let's say I have a class that holds a number `x`.  But I also need `2^x` (a "property" of `x`).  The basic class is:

```
class C {
    double x;

public:
    C() : x(0.0) 
    { }

    void inc() { x += 1; } 
    void dec() { x -= 1; } 
    void set(double x_) { x = x_; } 
};
```

But now I need to keep track of `2^x` and to keep updating this value every time `x` changes.  So I end up with

```
class expC {
    double expx;

public:        
    expC(const double &x) {
        recompute(x);
    }

    void inc() { expx *= 2; } // fast incremental change
    void dec() { expx /= 2; } // fast incremental change
    void recompute(const double &x) {
        expx = std::pow(2, x); // slow recomputation from scratch
    }
};


class C {
    double x;

    expC prop1; // XX

public:
    C() : x(0.0), prop1(x) // XX 
    { }

    void inc() { 
        x += 1;
        prop1.inc(); // XX 
    }
    void dec() { 
        x -= 1; 
        prop1.dec(); // XX
    }
    void set(double x_) { 
        x = x_;
        prop1.recompute(x); // XX
    }
};
```

`XX` marks changes I needed to make to the class `C`.  That's a lot of changes, which is error prone.  It becomes even more complicated with several properties, which my even depend on each other.

```
class C {
    double x;

    expC  prop1; // XX
    someC prop2; // XX

public:
    C() : x(0.0), prop1(x), prop2(x, prop1) // XX 
    { }

    void inc() { 
        x += 1;
        prop1.inc(); // XX 
        prop2.inc(); // XX 
    }
    void dec() { 
        x -= 1; 
        prop1.dec(); // XX
        prop2.dec(); // XX
    }
    void set(double x_) { 
        x = x_;
        prop1.recompute(x); // XX
        prop2.recompute(x, prop1); // XX
    }
};
```

**Question:** What is a good design for such a program?  I'm sure it's possible to do better than the above.  The goals are: 1) Make it easy to add/remove such properties or turn on/off their computation 2) Performance is critical.  `inc` and `dec` are called in tight inner loops and do relatively little. They cannot be made virtual for performance reasons.

In reality `x` is a more complex data structure.  Think e.g. adding/removing edges to/from a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) and keeping track of its degree sequence during the process.

---

**Update**

@tobi303 asked that I show how this class would be used.  It's in a manner similar to this:

```
void simulate(C &c) {
    for (/* lots of iterations */) {
        c.inc();
        double p1 = c.prop1.value();
        double p2 = c.prop2.value();
        if (condition(p1,p2))
            c.dec();
    }
}
```

Or in words:

- make a (random) change
- get property values after the change
- depending on the new property values, decide whether to accept or undo the change.

It's actually a Monte-Carlo simulation similar to a [Metropolis-Hasting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm).

A concrete example could be where the "data" in class `C` (state) is the spin state of an [Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) (for those familiar with it) and properties are the total energy and total magnetization of the system.  These are much faster to update after a single spin flip than to recompute from scratch.  In practice I don't have an Ising model, I have something a bit more complicated.  I have several properties, some fast to compute and some slow (actually I have some auxiliary data structures that help compute properties).  I need to experiment with combinations of different properties, so I often change what I include in the code.  Sometimes I implement new properties.  When I don't need an already implemented property, I need to be able to turn off its computation for performance reasons (some are really slow to compute).

Comment: imho it completely depends on what you are using this for. I am not even sure if I would define a class just to keep track of `x` and `2^x`. Depending on the use case a quite different data structure might be appropriate.

Comment: @tobi303 It's difficult to explain this concisely, so any help in how to make the question clearer is most appreciated.  In my actual problem the data is the adjacency matrix of a graph. Changes can be adding/removing an edge (as well as more complicated changes).  One of the simplest properties I need to keep track of is the degree of each node (but there are others too).

Comment: I understand that it is difficult to explain without making the example too complicated. Actually I think it is an interesting question but imho it would help if you add a short code snippet that uses the classes you introduced.

Comment: Are all the properties single values that could be computed in their own class?

Comment: @Stephen I just added an illustration of how I would use this.  In the end all properties are reduced to single numbers.  But to compute these properties I may need to keep track of more than a single number.  For example, I actually need to keep track of the degree of each node separately. The data structure I update incrementally is an integer vector.  However, in the end I only use a single number derived from this vector.

Comment: This question [seems to be too broad](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323603/4354477), but I'm not gonna vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

Just [be lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613551/good-practice-in-c-lazy-evaluation) and don't calculate the properties when you need to. It will remove plenty of code and unnecessary computation.

When you *do* need your property, compute it if it's not already in cache. So you need a boolean for each property to tell if the cache is up-to-date, and you need to invalidate the booleans each time `x` itself is updated.

Basically:

```
class C {
    double x;

    template <typename Value> struct cachedProp {
        bool cache = false;
        Value value;
    }

    cachedProp<expC> prop1;
    cachedProp<someC> prop2;
    //...

    void invalidateCache() {
         prop1.cache = false;
         prop2.cache = false;
         //...
    }
public:
    expC getProperty1() {
        if (!prop1.cache) {
            recalculateProp1();
            prop1.cache = true;
        }
        return prop1.value;
    }

    void inc() {
        x += 1;
        invalidateCache();
    }
};
```

Edit: an *even lazier* solution is to instead of storing a boolean in `cache`, store an integer correponding to the last update and maintain a counter in `C`. Each time the cache is invalidated, the counter in `C` is increased. When getting `propX`, if the counter doesn't match `propX.lastUpdate` then update `propX.

That way, invalidating cache is just one operation and doesn't have to update all the properties' cache.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that may work for you:

```
class C {
    double x;

    expC prop1;
    someC prop2;
    .
    .
    .

    template <typename F>
    void for_each_property(const F &f)
    {
        f(prop1,x);
        f(prop2,x,prop1);
        .
        .
        .
    }

public:
    C() : x(0.0), prop1(x), prop2(x, prop1)
    { }

    void inc()
    {
        x += 1;

        for_each_property([](auto &prop,auto&& ...) {
            prop.inc();
        });
    }

    void dec()
    {
        x -= 1;

        for_each_property([](auto &prop,auto&& ...) {
            prop.dec();
        });
    }

    void set(double x_)
    {
        x = x_;

        for_each_property([](auto &prop,auto&& ... args) {
            prop.recompute(args...);
        });
    }
};
```

When you add a new property, you only need to add one call in `for_each_property()`.  The use of variadics avoids the need to provide new overloads for different parameters as long as you stick to the same formula.

This doesn't eliminate the duplication in the constructor, unless you are willing to switch to doing default initialization of the properties and then call `set(0.0)`.