# Order of logical OR execution in C

Tags: c

Was wondering if the next statement could lead to a protection fault and other horrible stuff if value of next is NULL(node being a linked list).

```
if (!node->next || node->next->some_field != some_value) {
```

Im assuming the second part of the OR is not evaluated once the first part is true. Am I wrong in assuming this? Is this compiler specific?

Comment: You're not wrong. `if(ptr && ptr->foo == bar)` is safe, too. It's actually a code pattern used everyday by many programmers.

Comment: This is known as *"short-circuit evaluation"* should you need a term to search on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Little detail about using operator "or"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131972/little-detail-about-using-operator-or)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the ISO-IEC-9899-1999 Standard (C99), Section 6.5.14:

> The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare unequal
>   to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int. 4 Unlike the
>   bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation;
>   there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand.
>   If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not
>   evaluated.

This is not compiler-specific. If `node->next` is `NULL`, then the rest of the condition is **never** evaluated.

Comment: This of course exists in C89/C90 too (section 6.3.14 (ISO numbering)) with the same text. In ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (C11), which replaces C99 as the current C standard, the wording is slightly different, but conveys the same information.

Answer (score 6):

In an OR,

`if ( expr_1 || expr_2)`

expr_2 only gets 'tested' when expr_1 fails (is false)

In an AND

`if( expr_1 && expr_2 )`

expr_2 only gets 'tested' when expr_1 succeeds (is true)

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to assume that the right side boolean expression will not be evaluated if the left side evaluates to true. See [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683026/logical-comparisons-is-left-to-right-evaluation-guaranteed).

Answer (score 2):

It's not compiler specific. You can safely rely on short-circuiting and your code will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

It is `compiler independent` and always the `first` condition before `OR` operator(`!node->next`) is evaluated before evaluating the `second` condition(`node->next->some_field != some_value`) after `OR` operator.  If the `first` condition is `true`, the entire `expression` just evaluates to `true` without evaluating the `second` condition.

You are just making the best use of this feature for your `linked list`. You are going further to access `next` pointer only if it is `not NULL`.