# Using logical operator without any conditional statement or capturing in variable

Tags: c++, output, logical-operators, sequence-points

I have seen a kind of "poetic" code in some code base. Though it looks straight forward, just want to confirm, if it's in right direction.
In a very simple form:

```
bool foo ();  
bool bar ();  

int main () {
  foo() or bar();  // <--- line
}
```

Is the code at highlighted line as good as below snippet?

```
if(foo() == false)
  bar();
```

I am aware of `,` operator where all the statements are invoked, but unsure about `or` (equivalent to `||`) operator.
Testing in g++, it gives [expected output](http://ideone.com/4zmS27).

Comment: Throw a few trigraphs in this and it makes that poem downright painful, btw. =P. Regardless, your question is about multi-part boolean short-circuit evaluation, and yes, `exp1 || exp2` is *nearly* the same. The only thing missing is the unused `exp2` *result*, which in both cases is thrown out anyway (if it is reached in the first place, which only happens with `exp1` is zero-equivalent).

Comment: I am sorry @iammilind, but this is a dupe. Please next time make sure you google "C++ operators" or the like.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does C++ handle &&? (Short-circuit evaluation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211961/how-does-c-handle-short-circuit-evaluation)

Comment: @H2CO3, I am aware of the short circuit evaluation. But I was concerned about the receiving of the value which is not happening here. Not sure if they are duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, The `or` operator is the text equivalent of `||`.

So what you said is [correct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f355wky8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If the 1st condition is `true` the other one isn't evaluated anymore (in `||`'s case) and **therefore it's as you said**:

```
if(foo() == false)
  bar();
```

The same thing applies to `&&` when if the 1st condition is `false`, the second isn't evaluated anymore.

Comment: what if the second condition is false for &&. In &&, second condition is not evaluated if first is false.

Comment: sorry, it was a typo.. i meant the 1st is false. corrected answer