# Confused over while(cin >> x && x != 0) (when int x = 0) versus while(x != 0 && cin >> x ) (when int x = 1)

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, do-while

In my university's lecture today, we were given this:

input: 1, 2, 3, 0, 4

and two different codes

(1)

```
int x = 0;
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
while (cin >> x && x != 0) {
    sum += x;
    count++;
}
cout  << static_cast<double>(sum) / count;
```

(2)

```
int x = 1;
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
while (x != 0 &&  cin >> x ) {
    sum += x;
    count++;
}
cout  << static_cast<double>(sum) / count;
```

I understand the first code ends with an output of 2, but apparently the second output ends with an output of 1.5 (6/4). My confusion is over why the count is 4 if the loop becomes false after inputting zero - is it the location of the cin in the condition, the initialized x? I am confused. Thank you!

Comment: `int sum x = 0;` does not compile.

Comment: `int x = 1;` vs `int x=0;` is only to avoid the second code to step over the loop. The first code could have `int x = 1;` and there would be  no difference. Did they teach you how to use a debugger?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [How does C++ handle &&? (Short-circuit evaluation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211961/how-does-c-handle-short-circuit-evaluation). TL/DR: 1st loop doesn't count the number if read number is `0`, while the 2nd does.

Answer (score 4):

What happens when you reach the zero?

```
while (cin >> x && x != 0)
```

You read in the zero and discover that x is 0. You will stop iteration.

```
while (x != 0 && cin >> x)
```

Now `x` is set to zero, but you have checked *previous* value of `x`, which hasn't yet been zero *then*. So you will enter the loop again:

```
sum += 0; // the current value of x
count++;  // one summand more
```

and only discover that `x` got zero when checking the loop condition in the *subsequent* loop run.

In other words, in second variant, you count the zero as additional summand.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, the loop *is entered* with `x == 0`. It stops *after* adding 0 to `sum` and incrementing `count`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first loop the value 0 is not countered. While in the second loop the value 0 is countered in the variable count.

```
while (x != 0 &&  cin >> x ) { // <== 0 is read
    sum += x;
    count++;  // <-- and count is increased
}
```

In fact in the first loop the condition `x != 0` is a **pre-condition** while in the second loop the condition is a **post-condition**.

The second loop can be equivalently rewritten (provided that the input was successfull) like

```
do
{
    cin >> x;
    sum += x;
    count++;
} while ( x != 0 );
```