# Error C6011:Dereferencing NULL pointer 'NAME'. C++

Tags: c++, inner-classes, null-pointer

As in the title my code gives the said warning and mashes up the memory references.
I was tasked with using nested classes in C++. This code is mostly my code for linked lists from a previous C application but remade for C++.
I ve searched on the internet about said NULL exception and I can t figure it out.
I ll post the code and hope someone can give me some tips.
In the various links and tips on the internet it says that the pointer I am pointing to is referencing to a NULLptr, and that it can t accces a NULL address.
Tried to review it in various forms but it doesn t work.

Header

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class List
{
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node* next;
        Node() {
            this->data = NULL;
            this->next = NULL;
        }
    };
    Node* head;
public:
    List();
    void insertList(int data);
    void deleteFromList(int data);
    void deleteLowerThan(int lower);
    void calculateArithmetic();
    void showList();
};

#endif
```

Cpp file

```
List::List() {
    this->head = NULL;
}

void List::insertList(int n) {
    Node* new_node = new Node();


    new_node->data = n;

    new_node->next = head;

    head = new_node;

}

void List::deleteFromList(int n) {
    Node* temp = head;
    Node* prev = NULL;

    if (temp != NULL && temp->data == n) {
        head = temp->next;
        return;
    }

    while (temp->data != n && temp != NULL) {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    if (temp == NULL) return;

    prev->next = temp->next;
}

void List::deleteLowerThan(int n) {
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (temp->data < n) {
            deleteFromList(temp->data);
        }
        else {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}

void List::showList()
{
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Driver

```
int main() {
    List lista;
    lista.insertList(2);
    lista.insertList(4);
    lista.insertList(6);
    lista.insertList(8);
    lista.insertList(3);
    lista.insertList(1);
    lista.insertList(-4);
    lista.showList();
    lista.deleteFromList(4);
    lista.showList();
    lista.deleteFromList(8);
    lista.showList();
    lista.deleteFromList(6);
    lista.showList();
    lista.deleteLowerThan(3);
    lista.showList();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to switch the order here: `while (temp->data != n && temp != NULL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Adrian and Andy, this line causes `temp` to be dereferenced **before** you check if it's `NULL`:

```
while (temp->data != n && temp != NULL)
```

so, just check that it's not `NULL` first, *then* dereference it.

Other mentionable problems are the memory leaks. You should have exactly one `delete` for each `new` (unless you surrender the pointer to a smart pointer that will do `delete` for you).

```
void List::deleteFromList(int n) {
    Node* temp = head;
    Node* prev = head;         // set this if you need to delete head

    if(temp != nullptr && temp->data == n) {
        head = prev->next;
        delete prev;           // you forgot this
        return;
    }

    while(temp != nullptr && temp->data != n) {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    if(temp == nullptr) return;

    prev->next = temp->next;
    delete temp;              // you forgot this
}
```

You also need to implement a destructor in `List` to `delete` all the nodes in the `List` when it is destroyed.

A trickier bug is in your `deleteLowerThan()` function. You iterate over the nodes in your list and call `deleteFromList()` which will delete the very node you are currently on. In the next iteration, you use the same node pointer in `if (temp->data < n) {` causing undefined behaviour. In my case, the program seemed to just hang forever.

One possible fix:

```
void List::deleteLowerThan(int n) {
    Node* temp = head;
    int tmpdata;

    while(temp != nullptr) {
        tmpdata = temp->data; // save the nodes data
        temp = temp->next;    // step before you delete
        if(tmpdata < n) {
            deleteFromList(tmpdata);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your `deleteFromList` function, with this code:

```cpp
while (temp->data != n && temp != NULL) {
//...
```

Here, you are trying to check the value of `temp->data` ***before*** you have verified whether or not `temp` is `NULL`. Thus, you will, at some point (when you're at the end of the list, and `temp` *is* `NULL` be dereferencing a null pointer - which ain't good!

Instead, just invert the order of the comparisons:

```cpp
while (temp != NULL && temp->data != n) {
//...
```

This way, as soon as `temp` is `NULL`, the comparison's result will be fully known (see [short circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211961/how-does-c-handle-short-circuit-evaluation)), `temp->data` will ***not*** be evaluated, and the loop will stop running.

Comment: @Vlad Which compiler are you using? If you are using `g++` you can add `-fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address -g3` to get the exact function and line number where it happens - and it's indeed happening in the line Adrian points out. Changing this avoids the crash, but gets the program into an eternal loop.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Can you explain where the *eternal loop* happens? (I'm not saying it doesn't, just can't see where.)

Comment: Neither can I ... yet. It was just an observation when I ran it :-) The program is full of memory leaks though so it may have something to do with that. UB.