# Why are expressions not processed after a postfix increment and a conjunction operator?

Tags: c, increment, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

I bumped into a problem which prompted me to do some research. I have found that a piece of code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char i = 0;
    i++ && puts("Hi!");
    printf("%hhd\n", i);
}
```

only processes the increment, and outputs:

```
1
```

That is not the case if the postfix increment is replaced by a prefix one, it outputs:

```
Hi!
1
```

Why does it behave like that?

I apologise if the question is dumb.

Comment: Read about *short-circuit evaluation* of logical operators.

Comment: `&&` and `||` do short circuit evaluation.  If you say `x && y` then if x is false (0) then the whole expression is false and so the `y` part doesn't need to be evaluated.  And, in your program i *is* false (0) because it is incremented AFTERWARDS (it is a post increment)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211961/how-does-c-handle-short-circuit-evaluation  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-logical-operators-mandated-and-evaluation-order

Comment: It does not look like `i++` supposed to be evaluated as `true` of  `false`

Comment: `i++` evaluates to 0, and `i` gets incremented. So the left side of the logical AND is false, and the right side doesn't need to be evaluated.

Comment: Anything in C can be evaluated as `true` and `false`.

Comment: Everything is treated as true or false if it is part of a logical expression (like one containing `&&` or `||`) - a value of 0 is false and anything else is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
i++ &&  puts("Hi!");
```

`i` is evaluated before the increment. Because it's `0` the second part of the expression no longer needs to be evaluated, `0 && 0` is `0`, `0 && 1` is also `0`.

The same expression with a pre-increment means that `i` will be `1` when it's evaluated, in this case the second part of the expression is important, because `1 && 1` is possible, but `1 && 0` is also possible, and these will render different results.

Comment: That thought had just come to my mind when you posted this, you confirmed my suspicions :)

Comment: @Kaiyaha, well then, it seems the problem is solved :)

Comment: definitely, just have to wait for a couple of minutes to accept it