# while(pointer!=NULL && pointer->next!=NULL) vs while(pointer->next!=NULL && pointer!=NULL) in C++

Tags: c++, computer-science

I was trying to detect a cycle in a linked list. When I put the condition `while(pointer!=NULL && pointer->next!=NULL)`, it worked all fine, gave all the desirable outputs. But when I inverted the condition, it stopped showing output when no cycle exists. Like when a cycle exists its giving true as output, but when it doesn't exist its giving no outputs. So, I'm wondering what could the reason be behind it.

Comment: If the first condition is false, the second one is not checked. Checking `pointer->next` causes undefined behavior (most probably a crash) if `pointer` is null.

Comment: Look up "short circuit evaluation", for instance [How does C++ handle &&? (Short-circuit evaluation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211961/)

Answer (score 0):

Because the conditional is evaluated left-to-right. In your statement, 'pointer' and 'pointer->next' are values that you check against 'NULL'.

However, notice that accessing 'next' from 'pointer' requires that pointer itself be non-null. Trying to access an attribute from a null value results in undefined behaviour, which is what happened in your program

Thus, 'pointer' has to come before 'pointer->next' in the conditional statement. And, due to the use of the '&&' operator, the conditional is exited immediately if 'pointer' is null-checked first.

Answer (score -2):

The benefit of **&&** operator is that, wherever the condition gives first **false** value, the condition is not checked any further.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    struct ll{
        int value;
        struct ll* next;
    };
    struct ll* pointer;
    
    while(pointer != NULL && pointer->next != NULL){
        cout<< "pointer value:" << pointer <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:In the above program, I have not allocated space to the pointer variable.**

> while(pointer!=NULL && pointer->next!=NULL)

Since the first condition returned false so further part of condition is not checked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    struct ll{
        int value;
        struct ll* next;
    };
    struct ll* pointer;
    
    while(pointer->next != NULL && pointer != NULL){
        cout<< pointer->next << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:In the above program, I have not allocated space to the pointer variable.**

> while(pointer->next != NULL && pointer != NULL)

Here first condition is Invalid for comparision. So the program dumps here causing mostly segmentation fault.

Comment: `pointer != NULL` is not necessarily false. Since `pointer` is uninitialized, reading it is UB.

Comment: while printing the value of pointer just after its declaration, it shows value:0. 
The value of NULL is implementation defined, but is usually defined as the integer constant 0. 
So I thought its false as 0 != 0 is false.Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Some compilers [will warn you about it being uninitialized](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3YTKKvn44). *"Thanks for pointing it out."* Consider editing your answer to fix it.