# C++ 'AND' evaluation - standard guaranteed?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Safety concerns about short circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580945/safety-concerns-about-short-circuit-evaluation)

What does the standard say about evaluating `&&` expressions - does it guarantee that evaluation of parameters will stop at the first `false`?

E.g.:

```
Foo* p;
//....
if ( p && p->f() )
{
    //do something
}
```

is the `f()` guaranteed not to be called if `p == NULL`?

Also, is the order of evaluation guaranteed to be the order of appearence in the clause?

Might the optimizer change something like:

```
int x;
Foo* p;
//...
if ( p->doSomethingReallyExpensive() && x == 3 )
{
    //....
}
```

to a form where it evaluates `x==3` first? Or will it always execute the really expensive function first?

I know that on most compilers (probably all) evaluation stops after the first `false` is encountered, but what does the standard say about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the standard say about evaluating && expressions - does it guarantee that evaluation of parameters will stop at the first false?

Yes. That is called short-circuiting.

> Also, is the order of evaluation guaranteed to be the order of appearence in the clause?

Yes. From left to right. The operand before which the expression short-circuited doesn't get evaluated.

```
int a = 0;
int b = 10;
if ( a != 0 && (b=100)) {}

cout << b << endl; //prints 10, not 100
```

In fact, the above two points are the keypoint in my solution here:

- [Find maximum of three number in C without using conditional statement and ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074010/find-maximum-of-three-number-in-c-without-using-conditional-statement-and-ternary)

Answer (score 3):

In the ANSI C standard 3.3.13:

```
Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees
left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the
evaluation of the first operand.  If the first operand compares equal
to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.
```

There is an equivalent statement in the C++ standard

Answer (score 1):

`&&` (and `||`) establish sequence points. So the expression on the left-hand side will get evaluated before the right-hand side. Also, yes, if the left-hand side is false/true (for `&&`/`||`), the right-hand side is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

> What does the standard say about evaluating && expressions - does it guarantee that evaluation of parameters will stop at the first false?
>
> Also, is the order of evaluation guaranteed to be the order of appearence in the clause?

5.14/1. Unlike &, && guarantees left-to-right evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the ﬁrst operand is false.

This only works for the standard && operator, user defined overloads of `operator &&` don't have this guarantee, they behave like regular function call semantics.

> Might the optimizer change something like:
>   if ( p->doSomethingReallyExpensive() && x == 3 )
>   to a form where it evaluates x==3 first?

An optimizer may decide to evaluate `x == 3` first since it is an expression with no side-effects associated if `x` is not modified by `p->doSomethingReallyExpensive()`, or even evaluate it after `p->doSomethingReallyExpensive()` already returned false. However, the visible behavior is guaranteed to be the previously specified: Left to right evaluation and short-circuit. That means that while `x == 3` may be evaluated first and return false the implementation still has to evaluate `p->doSomethingReallyExpensive()`.