# Short-circuiting and readability

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, readability, short-circuiting

In this line

`if ((last_search == NULL) || (last_search != NULL && total_results != 0))`

I know that C's short-circuit evaluation rules say that only if `last_search` is not null will it try and evaluate the right-hand side of `||`, hence it's equivalent to writing

`if ((last_search == NULL) || (total_results != 0))`

and I was advised to use the later by someone, but still isn't the former more readable? Also won't the compiler optimize out the redundant `last_search != NULL`?

Comment: No, and yes. Less code is more.

Comment: Side note : I'd rather move constant to left,  `(NULL == last_search)...`,

Comment: @a1ex07 I know it's just personal preference (and I know I've seen a trend toward this lately), but to me putting the constant on the left makes it harder to read. I read that as "if NULL is equal to ...", which is just wrong, because NULL is a constant and doesn't change. "if last_search is equal to ..." is a much more natural and understandable reading to me.

Comment: Things that are obvious should not be mentioned..and so the first case, in a way, just has some redundancy.

Comment: @a1ex07 I think moving constants to the left is a bad advice. You are testing if `last_search` value is `NULL` and not if `NULL` is `last_search` value.

Comment: @twalberg: having `val==NULL` in conditions is a way more error-prone (`val=NULL` is absolutely valid -opposite to `NULL=val`- but means different)...

Comment: @a1ex07 Yeah, I get why it's being done. I just think it reduces readability.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is subjective, but no, the first variant is not more readable because there's more to read. The most readable code (and the least buggy!) is that which does not exist. Just think what would happen if you wanted to check 3 or 4 conditions at once.

And here's another counterexample: would you write code like this?

```
if (number < 0) {
}
else if(number >= 0) {
    // why not just "else"?
}
```

As for performance: the compiler would probably optimize the redundant call away, but undoing the performance degradation does not help with the readability degradation.

Comment: +1. If I want to emphasize the `number>=0` (e.g. after a very long if-block), I move the if-part of the elseif into a comment.

Answer (score 5):

No it's not. The second one is a lot more readable. Why would you keep the redundant check in there, regardless of whether the compiler will optimize it away?

The first version tells you that `last_search` is not `NULL` because it got there, but if you can't tell that from the first condition (`last_search == NULL` failed), you've probably got bigger issues than readability.

Comment: +1 for you because this answer is just as good as Jon's yet you got none of the upvotes because he has more rep...

Comment: @H2CO3 to be fair, I too upvoted him for "The most readable code is that which does not exist.". :)

Comment: @H2CO3: Wait till you see what happens when you answer a question and Jon Skeet does the same... btw, I also upvoted this because Luchian was first.

Comment: @Jon been there. Fortunately, it doesn't happen too often, I rarely follow Java (and C# is far from my thing)...

Comment: @Jon yeah, it's just the same with Jon Skeet. Everybody upvotes him just because he's Jon Skeet. And I wouldn't mind it if it was because he had the best answer. Of course, in a big part of the cases, he has the best answer, but when not, then why?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore +1 for "C# is far from my thing". I don't understand how a Microsoft (non-)technology can be the leading topic on SO. Oh wait, SO itself is written in ASP? Well played, tech world...

Answer (score 1):

It is not only the short circuit evaluation that makes it unreadable but also the fact of using superfluous comparisons.

```
if ( !last_search || total_results)
```

is much easier to read than anything that you proposed.

Comment: The problem with this is what if the value of `NULL` isn't `false`?  `NULL` is just a constant (i hope it is, anyway - if it isn't, there's more problems going on here), and as such, may actually correspond to something that won't evaluate as false.  Use "if ((last_search == NULL) || total_results)"

Comment: @AJMansfield `NULL` will always evaluate as false. Even if its underlying representation is not all zeros.

Comment: conversion of pointer values to obtain a logical condition is well defined by the standard. It does exactly what you would expect: it is `false` when the pointer is a null pointer. Just use the tools that the standard offers.

Comment: @Dave Isn't `NULL` here a compiler constant?  What if its being used as a placeholder (e.g. `-1`)?  Although I agree that if it is, there are more problems with the code than just this.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm just not very familiar with C.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @AJMansfield, ok, no problem. But could you please avoid editing an answer for something your are not very familiar with?

Comment: @Jens Gustedt Sorry my browser was having some trouble, I thought it was writing a comment, and I couldn't figure out how to delete the edit.

Comment: @AJMansfield, ah, ok, that explains it.

Comment: IMHO, that is is horrible and does not explain what you are doing. == NULL and != 0 make it extremely clear what is going on

Comment: @TomTanner, I think this is just a matter of habits, nothing else. And occasionally it is exactly the way it is foreseen by the C standard since the beginning. Here it makes even one thing more apparent than in the other versions: in this case the condition is completely symmetric, there is no reason that one of the conditions has to be evaluated before the other.

Comment: I'm not objecting to ||. It's the lack of equality testing. Whether or not short circuiting is good for parallel evaluation is a different question entirely