# Precedence order in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i=-3, j=2, k=0, m;
   m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
   printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k, m);
   return 0;
}
```

why is the output giving result -2 2 0 1?

one logic is ( ++j&& ++k) is not computed as ++i is non zero

but as && has higher preference than || why they are not computed

Comment: Higher precedence doesn't mean first to execute.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/628526/811335

Comment: Read about sequence points.

Comment: Thanks Cubbi and Noor1..it cleared lot of my doubts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precedence does not specify the order in which an expression is evaluated. It specifies how an expression is interpreted. In this case, the precedence rules of C (which are embedded in its formal grammar) cause `a || b && c` to be interpreted as `a || (b && c)`.

When this expression is evaluated, the rules of C specify that `a` must be evaluated first. The rules also state that if `a` is true, then value of the entire expression is true, and the right side of the `||` is not evaluated.

To see this more clearly, consider the expression `a + b < c * d`. The precedence rules cause this to be interpreted as `(a + b) < (c * d)`. However, unlike `||`, the rules of C do not specify that the left side of `<` must be evaluated first. The compiler may evaluate `a + b` first or `c * d` first, even though `*` has higher precedence than `+`. The compiler is allowed to use any evaluation order that gets the right answer.

The only order imposed here is that `a + b` and `c * d` must both be evaluated before the `<` can be evaluated. However, that comes from the structure of the expression, not the rules of precedence.

Answer (score 4):

Operators `&&` and `||` computation order is left-to-right. Compiler guarantees that operator's `||` right operand will not be computed if left operand evaluates to true.

Comment: It should be the language to establish the guarantee.

Comment: but as && has higher prefernce than || shouldn't the expression involving && should be evaluated first.

Comment: @user1495306: precedence affects grouping; it doesn't affect order of evaluation.  `||` and `&&` guarantee left-to-right evaluation, period.  The expression `++i || ++j && ++k` is interpreted as "the result of the expression `++i` OR the result of the expression `++j && ++k`."  `++i` is evaluated first; `++j && ++k` will only be evaluated if the result of `++i` is 0.

Answer (score 1):

`m = ++i || ++j && ++k;`

`++i` will executes first. Since, `i` will become `-2` ,which means/equivalent to `true`. It won't execute `++j && ++k` part and `m` value will be `1`.

So, final output will become `-2 2 0 1`

When executing `||`, it will executes the left hand part first and if it `true` then it won't proceed to right. Since, it is not going matter, whether right-part is `true` or `false`. So, in you case, left part of `||` executed and since it return non-zero value that means `true`.

Comment: but why? as && has more prefernce than || shouldn't the expression (++j && ++k) be evaluated first

Comment: please read my answer, as i said it will start execution from `++i`.

Comment: @user No. Precedence just changes which operators are applied to which operands, it doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the order of execution. As || is defined as not evaluating it's second operand if the first evaluates to true, it can't evaluate (++j && ++k).

Answer (score 1):

Due to short circuit evaluation

```
m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
```

is equivalent to

```
++i;
m = i != 0;
if(!m) {
  ++j;
  m = j != 0;
  if(m) {
    ++k;
    m = k != 0;
  }
}
```