# Uninitialized char

Tags: c++

I'm reading over a C++ class for parsing CSV files in one of my programming books for class. I primarily write in C# for work and don't interact with C++ code very often. One of the functions, getline, uses an uninitialized char variable and I'm confused as to whether it's a typo or not.

```cpp
// getline: get one line, grow as needed
int Csv::getline(string& str)
{
    char c;

    for (line = ""; fin.get(c) && !endofline(c); )
        line += c;
    split();
    str = line;
    return !fin.eof();
}
```

`fin` is an istream. The documentation I'm reading shows the `get (char& c);` function being passed a reference, but which char in the stream is returned? What's the initial value of `c`?

Comment: the initial value of local variable is not defined,it could be anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial value of `c` is undefined but it does not matter what the initial value of `c` is since the call to `get` will set the value.  Since there is a [sequence point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/628554) after the left hand side of the `||` and `&&` operators we know that all the [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) of `get` will have been effected and `endofline` will see the modified value of `c`.

Comment: So `c` is set to the first character in the stream. Thanks.