# The semantics of checking if conditions

Tags: c, short-circuiting

If I have a condition like this:

```
if (X && Y) {}
```

Will the compiler check `Y` if `X` is false? Is it compiler dependent?

Comment: if it's really empty like that the compiler will probably optimize it out and neither will be checked. :)

Comment: Probably duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order

Comment: the check is done in the execution runtime and not in the compilation phase

Comment: @Mike: If there's a function call involved I highly doubt that any compiler will optimize it away - unless it knows for sure that the function call does not have any side-effects.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - true, a simple type (`int`, `char`, ...) was assumed for that comment

Comment: Also, I did not mean an empty if-block either :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C and [most other languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) short-circuit evaluation is guaranteed. So `Y` is only evaluated if `X` evaluates to true.

The same applies to `X || Y` - in this case `Y` is only evaluated if `X` evaluates to false.

See [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15638629/298479) for a reference to the C specification where this behavior is mentioned and guaranteed.

Comment: isn't C allowed to evaluate `Y` first, then maybe `X`?

Comment: No, not at all. That would actually be horrible: `if(x && x->foo)` - what if `x` was NULL?

Comment: In that case,  you'd need to check `x` and then `x->foo`, in two separate `if` statements I distinctly remember having done this.

Comment: @JanDvorak - see my answer below. It's in the C specification that it will be left-to-right evaluation. You may have had to do it for the bit-wise operator.. or maybe you had a non-compliant C compiler. ;)

Answer (score 7):

The C specs (6.5.13) clarifies this point for you:

> 4 Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator **guarantees left-to-right evaluation**;
>   if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of
>   the first and second operands. **If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated.**

So the C language itself defineds that if `X == 0` then `Y` will not be checked.

Answer (score 3):

the `Y` is checked only if the `X` is `true`

If `X` is false then `Y` will not be checked

**BTW** The check is done in the execution runtime and not in the compilation phase

Answer (score 1):

Both the `&&` and `||` force left-to-right evaluation.  Both will introduce a sequence point between the first and second operands if the second operand is evaluated.  Neither will evaluate the second operand  if the result of the expression can be determined from the first operand alone.  IOW, for `X && Y`, `Y` will not be evaluated if `X` is false, whereas for `X || Y`, `Y` will not be evaluated if `X` is true.

Note that precedence does not affect order of evaluation; given an expression like `X || Y && Z`, `Y && Z` will *not* be evaluated before `X`, even though `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.  `X` is evaluated first; if the result is 0 (false), then `Y` is evaluated.  If that result is non-zero (true), then `Z` is evaluated.

This is defined in sections 6.5.13 and 6.5.14 of the [language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (2011 version, online draft), so it is not compiler-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If `Y` has side-effects, or if accessing it might be undefined behavior (e.g. bad pointer dereference), then the compiler must ensure that `Y` is not evaluated unless `X` evaluated to true. However, if both `X` and `Y` lack side effects and the compiler knows access to them is well-defined, it might choose to optimize in such a way that both accesses happen.