# Does relational operator affect assignment operator operations?

Tags: c

Why the output of below mentioned program is `0` not `20` ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 10, j = 0;
    if (i || (j = i + 10))
       /* do something */;                
    printf("%d\n",j);
}
```

Comment: Short circuited boolean expression.

Comment: This may seem like a silly question but I'm learning - how could the program ever output 20? Is it something to do with C specifically?

Comment: @Andy **(1)**--program could output `20`, only if `i = 0` (that give change to execute expression `j = i + 10`). **(2)** No, this code is valid in C++, even in Java because in both we can do  `=` within `if()` and both support short-circuit. --- It would be interesting to know even [Python supports short-circuit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting/14892812#14892812) but this expression `if (i || (j = i + 10))` is not valid in Python because `=` in `if` is syntax error.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thanks for that! I thought that would be the case but I was just a little confused by the fact `i` is hard coded to equal 10

Comment: @Andy yes, and you know na **?** that any `non-0` value is `true` in C  and so `i` (=10) is `ture`.

Comment: Hello, This is first time I am getting this much response for my question. It makes difficult to accept the answer, sorry for changing  3 times. :) Thanks Paul and Grijesh :)

Comment: @JeshwanthKumarNK I added in my answer that `||` and `&&` operators introduces sequence point so `++i || ++i` is not a undefined behaviour   :) whereas `++i | ++i` is Undefined :( . got it?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Just tested :) Ya you are right :) I got it :) Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, the concept is called [Short-Circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (in logical `&&`, `||` operators expression).

In the case of any logical expression (includes `||`, `&&`) compiler stop evaluation expression as soon as result evaluated (and save executions).

The technique for short-circuit is:

`!0 || any_expression` == `1`, so `any_expression` not need to evaluate.

And because in your expression `i` is not zero but its 10, so you can think if consdition `(i || (j = i + 10))`  just as `i`.

> **Logical OR operator:**
>   The `||` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; there is a
>   sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand. If the first
>   operand compares `unequal` to `0`, the second operand is `not`
>   evaluated.

Similarly for  && (and operator):
 `0 && any_expression` == `0`, so `any_expression` not need to evaluate.

In your expression:

```
(i || (j = i + 10) )
      ------------
       ^
       | Could evaluate if i is 0, 
       as i = 10 (!0 = true), so j remains unchanged as second operand is not evaluated
```

For or `||` operator answer can be either 0, 1. To save execution, evaluation stops as soon as results find. So if first operand is  non-zero result will be `1`  (as above) for the expression. So for first operand `i = 10` compares unequal to 0,  the second operand `(j = i + 10)` is not evaluated so `j` remains `0` hence output of your code is `0`.

Note: Short-circuit behavior is not only in present in C but concept is common to many languages like Java, C++, Python. (but not all e.g. VB6).

In C short-circuiting of logical expressions is guaranteed has always been a feature of C. It was true when Dennis Ritchie designed and implemented the first version of C, still true in the 1989 C standard, and remains true in the C99 standard.

A related post: [Is short-circuiting boolean operators mandated in C/C++? And evaluation order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order)

Comment: Honestly, far too long answer.

Comment: *"In the case of any logical expression most compiler stop evaluation expression as soon as result evaluated (to save executions)."* - No, it isn't done by *"most compilers"*, but by *all* that call themselves C compilers, because it is mandated by the standard. So more often than not this isn't just for the sake of performance but correctness, e.g. think about `while(node && node->value)`, which would be terribly wrong if the standard didn't *guarantee* short-cirtuiting.

Comment: @ChristianRau I disagree with you. Original purpose of short-circuit to  get  performance. And I perfectly understand `while(node && node->value)` its second benefit of short-circuit.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You might disagree with that (only the standard comitte can answer that and you might very well be correct about the original purpose). You can however in absolutely no way disagree with the fact that not *"most compilers"* do this, but *all*. A compiler that doesn't do this is not a C compiler and it would be just like something like `=` or `+` wouldn't work as expected, you cannot rely on any code to work with such a compiler. As it stands you answer sounds like this is just a compiler implementation optimization, which is *not* the case.

Comment: @Grijesh: you should clarify the part in your answer about "most compilers" because at present it sounds like you're suggesting that not all C compilers adhere to the C language standard in this regard. It's confusing at best - you should probably limit the scope of the answer to C.

Comment: @Grijesh: you just need to clarify that sentence so that people don't get the wrong idea when they read your answer. You can see that already two people have misunderstood your answer. One of the great thing about SO is that answers can always be *improved*.

Comment: @PaulR that is the way one should write comment. Thanks I appreciate it. and I try to improve my answer.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that has removed the ambiguity - down-vote now converted to up-vote.

Comment: *"Please take time before down-vote."* - I *took* time to read and understand the answer before downvoting. I even took the time to repeatedly clarify my problems with the answer in clear, objective and constructive comments. I'm glad things are finally sorted out now.

Comment: @JeshwanthKumarNK hey Jeshwanth! my old answer was even correct Parul R. and christianRau was just helping me to remove ambiguity/a confusing statement in old version answer. Please feel free to accept any answer you wants. And if you have any doubt left let us know.

Answer (score 20):

`||` is a [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) operator - if the left hand side evaluates to true then the right hand side does not need to be evaluated. So, in your case, since `i` is true then the expression `j = i + 10` is not evaluated. If you set `i` to 0 however then the right hand side *will* be evaluated,

Comment: is this feature compiler dependent?

Comment: @TheJoker No, In C short-circuiting of logical expressions is guaranteed has always been a feature of C.

Answer (score 5):

In `if (i || (j = i + 10))`, there are two boolean expression to evaluate. The thing is, the first one is true, therefore there is no need to compute the second. It's purely ignored.

Answer (score 3):

because `||` is a short-circuit operator (so is the `&&` operator).

so in `(i || j = i+10)`, `i` is 10, left part of `||` is true, the expression `j = i+10` didn't happen, as a result, `j=0`.