# If statement not calling all methods returning BOOL

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I have code like this:

```
-(IBAction)send {        
    if ([self isCorrect1] && [self isCorrect2] && ...) {
        [self sendRequest];
    }
}

-(BOOL)isCorrect1 {
     ...
}

-(BOOL)isCorrect2 {
     ...
}
```

Every `isCorrect` method is checking some condition showing some message in the view and returning result of the checking. I noticed that if first condition is false it will only show error message for the first method (and I need all of them to be checked) and no breakpoint is triggered inside these methods. I thought it was some kind of LLVM optimization so I created code like this:

```
-(IBAction)send {
    BOOL correct = [self isCorrect1];
    correct = correct && [self isCorrect2];
    ...

    if (correct) {
        [self sendRequest];
    }
}
```

And is still not working correctly. Do I have to create new BOOL variable to store result for the check or is there some other way?

Comment: Sure it doesn't. The logical or operator short-circuits. There are hundreds of dupes of this question already.

Comment: What is you requirement basically?

Comment: In this case ( all && ) if statement will stop checking after first NO

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is short-circuiting boolean operators mandated in C/C++? And evaluation order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order)

Comment: Ok but what with `correct = correct &&` approach. Why it's short-cutting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the first condition is evaluated to `false`, it won't check for the rest of the conditions and will go to the `else` part straightaway.

Try this.

```
BOOL finalResult = [self isCorrect1];
finalResult = [self isCorrect2] && finalResult;
finalResult = [self isCorrect3] && finalResult;
finalResult = [self isCorrect4] && finalResult;
...

if (finalResult) {

}
```

This will go through all of the `isCorrect` tests and will let you know if it passed all of them in the end or not.

Comment: This has the same short-circuiting behaviour as the OP's original code (namely, evaluation will stop at the first failing condition, and remaining conditions are not evaluated)

Comment: Changed order of the method and the flag will stop compiler from short-cutting?

Comment: Checked - it works with LLVM 5.0 and it's more clean than other solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you see is the expected behaviour of the `&&`, namely, it "short-circuits" the evaluation, if it can determine the result in advance, before having evaluated all conditions:

```
expression-yielding-false && something-else
```

The result of the above is completely determined by the first part; regardless of what the second operand yields, the final result is false. This allows you to write something like:

```
if (obj != null && obj->count == 3) 
{
    ...
}
```

If the `&&` did not have the short-circuit behaviour, you'd have to write

```
if (obj != null) 
{
    if (obj->count == 3)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

The `||` has a similar behaviour. In case of

```
something-yielding-true || anything
```

the right-hand side cannot affect the result value, as the left-hand side already returned true.

One possible work-around would be:

```
int succeeses = 0;

succeesses += [self isCorrect1]? 1 : 0;
succeesses += [self isCorrect2]? 1 : 0;
succeesses += [self isCorrect3]? 1 : 0;

if (successes == 3) 
{
    // All tests did succeed
}
else
{
    // At least one failed.
}
```

If you need to know, which tests passed, and which failed, you can try:

```
BOOL passed1 = [self isCorrect1];
BOOL passed2 = [self isCorrect2];
BOOL passed3 = [self isCorrect3];

if (passed1 && passed2 && passed3) 
{
    // All tests did succeed
}
else
{
    // At least one failed.
}
```

A more dense version of the above would be

```
int passed = 0;

passed |= [self isCorrect1]? (1 << 0) : 0;
passed |= [self isCorrect2]? (1 << 1) : 0;
passed |= [self isCorrect3]? (1 << 2) : 0;

if (passed == 7) 
{
    // All tests did succeed
}
else
{
    if (passed & (1 << 0)) 
    {
        // First test passed
    }
    else 
    {
        // First test failed
    }
    if (passed & (1 << 1)) 
    {
        // Second test passed
    }
    else 
    {
        // Second test failed
    }
    if (passed & (1 << 2)) 
    {
        // Third test passed
    }
    else 
    {
        // Third test failed
    }
}
```

which is simply a more occult formulation of the version with a boolean variable per test tried.

Comment: Thank you for examples. Second one worked for me. I would argue that third approach is an overkill for readability.

Comment: I tend to agree. The only advantage is, that you can evaluate, which conditions failed, using a `switch` statement, too, which is helpful sometimes.