# Confusion with usage of Increment Operator

Tags: c, linux

I am learning C. I came across the following program -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int var1 = 2, var2 = 6;
  var2 = var2 || var1++ && printf("Computer World");
  printf("%d %d\n", var1, var2);
  return 0;
}
```

After compilation with gcc 4.4.5 on Ubuntu 10.10, I'm getting the output as -

```
2 1
```

I understand how 'var2' is set to 1.

Even thought there is a increment operator on 'var1', why it is not incremented when we see the console output?

Comment: That is not the output of that program.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart he probably meant `2 1` and mistakenly added a prompt before that. But *I* do not understand how `var2` is set to 1...

Comment: @icedwater You are right... I'll not add that next time ... Seems to cause confusion.

Comment: Yes, because $ marks variables in bash, too. e.g. defining `var2=50` in a bash script will return `50` when you `echo $var2`.

Comment: Who will write a code like this var2 = var2 || var1++ && printf("Computer World");, anyways var2 is positive hence no operation at RHS and assigns true which 1 to var2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var2 || var1++ && printf("Computer World");
```

is a logic operation so if the `var2` is `true` (var2 is not equal to zero) then the second logic operation `var1++ && printf("Computer World");` will not be executed (It's called a [short-circuit operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)) . So that's why the `var1` is not incremented

Try to inverse your logic operation in this way and you will get the `var1` incremented:

```
var2 = var1++ && printf("Computer World") || var2;
```

Comment: It's called a [short-circuit operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: the second logic operation **may** not get executed. It's unspecified.

Comment: @Njol thank you for the help I updated my answer with your remark

Comment: @Dariusz Citation please?

Comment: @Dariusz I think that actually it is specified for both `c` and `c++`. This is why compilers cannot naturally paralellize complex logic statements. EDIT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order I guess one needs to be careful. But in `c` and generally `c++` you can depend on it.

Comment: Thank you all for telling about this pitfall.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that logical `&&` and `||` are evaluated left-to-right. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

In C, `||` is a shortcut operator, which means in an expression such as `exp1 || exp2`, if the truth value of this expression can be determined by evaluating `exp1`, `exp2` would not be evaluated.

For example, in your case, the result of evaluating `var2` is `6`, which is true in C, so other part of the expression, which is `var1++ && printf("Computer World")`, would not be evaluated.

You can see [Shortcut Operators](http://logos.cs.uic.edu/Examples%20And%20Notes/notes/C++/Ch2/Operators.htm) for further details.