# When is the R.H.S. of && and ++ evaluated?

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    printf("%d\n", a++ && b++ || c++); //Here, a++ gives 0. Still, c++ is evaluated.
    printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c); //Prints 1 0 1

    a = 1, b = 0, c = 0;
    printf("%d\n", a++ || b++ && c++); //Here, a++ gives 1 and only a++ is evaluated.
    printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c); //Prints 2 0 0
}
```

Why is it that when L.H.S. of && gives 0, the R.H.S. of || is evaluated? Whereas in the second case, L.H.S. of || gives 1 and nothing is evaluated beyond that?

Comment: Your question should be answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/628526/149530)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because precedence of operators. First `&&` is evaluated, then `||`.

```
printf("%d\n", a++ && b++ || c++);
```

is equivalent to

```
printf("%d\n", (a++ && b++) || c++);
```

```
printf("%d\n", a++ || b++ && c++);
```

is equivalent to

```
printf("%d\n", a++ || (b++ && c++));
```

Hope that makes it clearer for you.