# Conditions in IF with AND how it will be parsed

Tags: c++, c, conditional-statements

This seems to be trivial but I forget how conditions are treated,
`if(!a && b)` here if `a` is `true` then it will check for `b` also? or it will see the `&&` and stop?

Comment: Are you referring to the logical AND operator(`&&`)? In that case, it will not check `b` if `a` is true. Read about short-circuiting.

Comment: @CoolGuy [`and` is the same as `&&`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative).

Comment: Damn, was just about to mark it a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order

Comment: Ok so it seems that `the && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated`
Thanks

Comment: @zenith , I did not know that because I'm not familiar with C++ much. Thanks for the info!

Comment: So to not open a new question, for this case `if(!(a=b))` firstly a takes b value and then it;s evaluated? For ex if b=0 then that condition will be true right?