# Short-circuiting of non-booleans

Tags: c++, c

Is it safe to shorten this usage of the ternary operator:

```
process_ptr(ptr ? ptr : default_ptr);
```

with the short-circuit:

```
process_ptr(ptr || default_ptr);
```

in C and C++? In other words, are we guaranteed to get *either* `ptr` *or* `default_ptr` back from the experssion, or is it perhaps allowed for the expression to result in an arbitrary "logical true" value, if the expression is logically true?

This is the kind of code you'd see all over Perl code, but I rarely see it in C/C++, that's the original basis of my question.

Comment: I am almost sure that `ptr || default_ptr` will evalute to `1` or `0`.

Comment: The conditional expression will return a value but the logical expression will always return either 0 or 1.

Comment: Did you consider checking the result to see if your hypothesis that it *could* be safe is valid? (You would have had the answer by now.)

Comment: As a side note, you can refer to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: "I rarely see it in C/C++". Perhaps the reason is that such code won't even compile in most cases?

Comment: @n.m. It could compile, with a warning like `making pointer from integer without a cast`.

Comment: @iharob: The reverse: "implicit conversion of pointer to integer". Hmm.. actually not, as the test if for NULL-pointer. Yes: it is valid.

Comment: "_I rarely see it in C/C++."_ Perhaps the reason is that C/C++ doesn't exist?

Comment: Just a curiousity: GCC has the non-Standard behaviour of supporting `ptr ?: default_ptr` to get the behaviour sought in this question... [docs here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/Conditionals.html).  You may want to tune your warnings if you actually use this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second expression will evaluate to either `1` or `0`.

Quoting the C11 standard draft:

> **6.5.14 Logical OR operator**
>
> 3. The `||` operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type `int`.

So the two expressions are very different, since one of them yields a pointer, and the other one an integer.

**Edit**:

One of the comments claims that this answer is only valid for c, and @[Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit)  is right.

There are also answers that are only correct for c++<sup>1</sup>, although the only difference with them is that c++ has type `bool` and then it evaluates this expression as `bool` instead of `int`. But [apparently there is an important issue with overloading `||` operator in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/628554/1983495), which prvents short-citcuiting  to *apply* for the object that overloads it.

So for c++ there are more things to consider, but since this question was tagged with both languages tags, then it's necessary to mention at least the differece.

The rule still applies when short-circuiting applies, i.e. the result of the evaluation of the expressions is either `1` or `0` for c and `true` or `false` for c++.

---

<sup>1</sup> Like these answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30621471/1983495), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30621597/1983495)

Comment: The edit to your answer doesn't make sense, I think because you misquoted @LightnessRacesinOrbit as claiming the answer is only valid in C++ (which makes the second paragraph seem confusing and contradictory).  Additionally, I don't see the point of the link to the YouTube flame-bait claiming that C and C++ should be one language.

Comment: @jadarnel27 The link to the video, is just to note that even though c and c++ are not the same languages c++ tries to be as much as possible like c, because the original intention of the creator was to make it one language.

Comment: @jadarnel27: It's also misleading/wrong because it suggests that the only difference between C and C++ is the type of the expression when, in fact, short-circuiting — ostensibly the very point of this question — only works on built-in boolean operators. [Once you overload them, a C++ feature, that goes away](http://stackoverflow.com/a/628554/560648). I probably wouldn't have bothered commenting otherwise. Thus, the answer is still sort of wrong. That said, despite the title, it's difficult to see where short-circuiting _really_ fits into this question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I see your point, you're right, and that's one of the reasons why I don't like c++, it's so complicated.

Comment: @iharob: It really is awful :)

Answer (score 5):

Concerning the Perl style, which usually is of type

```
do_someting || die("didn't work")
```

This would work in C++ also.

```
function_returning_bool(some) || std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
```

This is due to the `||` being a logical OR operator and causing the short-circuit in this case if the return value is true.

But using it instead of the ternary operator is impossible.

```
std::cout << ("asd" || "dsa");
```

This will result in `1` being output.

Comment: Nitpick, if the return value from `function_returning_bool()` is a class with an overridden `operator||()` method, then short-circuiting won't happen....

Comment: @AndreKostur Thanks, forgot about that. I always appreciate nitpicking :)

Comment: Obviously, it's a matter of taste whether `condition() || exec_on_false()` is good style. I'd rather say it isn't: since the result is boolean, you can pretty much only use it for side-effect-only functions, and for these you might as well use an `if`, which is much clearer.

Answer (score 3):

No. The result type is `int` (or `bool` in C++), and will be either `1` or `0` (`true` or `false` in C++).

Answer (score 3):

`operator||` for pointers returns a `bool`, so `ptr || default_ptr` will evaluate to `true` if either `ptr` or `default_ptr` are non-null.