# C++ precedence order

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

I was trying to solve a question to insert a node into a sorted double linked list 
To insert an element to the end of the list I used a simple loop in which the pointer move till the element to insert is less than the one in the list or it hits NULL. 
My loop works when the condition is

```
while ( cur !=NULL && cur->data < data ) {
    prev = cur ; 
    cur = cur->next; 
}
```

But doesn't work when the condition is

```
while ( cur->data < data && cur !=NULL ) {
    prev = cur ; 
    cur = cur->next; 
}
```

can someone explain why this happens ?

Comment: In second case, do you get sigmentation fault?

Comment: If `cur` is actually null then the second case will dereference a null pointer.  The thing on the left of `&&` happens before the thing on the right.

Comment: Or this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order