# how do we interpret the `||` and `&&` in an assignment statement?

Tags: c

I have been coding from a long time though I'm still a student programmer/ I'm usually good at programming but when questions like the one below are asked I get stuck. What will be the output and why of the following program?

```
int main() 
    {
        int i=4,j=-1,k=0,w,x,y,z;
        w=i||j||k;
        print("%d",w);
        return 0;
    }
```

output:
1
why this result? what does the statement `w=||j||k;` means?

Comment: Can somebody also explain the +1 on this question?

Comment: Why should it mean anything different than in a condition?

Comment: Another way to write this would be `w = ((i != 0) || (j != 0) || (k != 0));` where I only put the brackets for clarity. Each part such as `(i != 0)` will evaluate to `0` or `1`. Remember, in a C boolean test it is implied that `0` is `false` and all other values are `true`.

Comment: There are many other dups of this one on SO. You may want to read [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 3):

`i  || j || k` is evaluated from left to right. It does that:

`i == 4`, which is true, so ORing it with any other value will yield true. That's it<sup>1</sup>.

The rest of the statement is not evaluated because `||` and `&&` are [*short-circuit* operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order), that is, if in your statement `i != 0`, neither `j` nor `k` will be evaluated because the result is guaranteed to be `1`. `&&` works similarly.
That's important to remember if you have something like `f() || k()`, where `k` has some side effect like an output to screen or a variable assignment; it might not be executed at all.

The **bitwise** OR operator `|` really ORs the bitwise representations of the values instead; it evaluates **all its operands**.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks to @SouravGosh on that!</sub>

Comment: This answer maybe is misleading, as in case of `1 || k`, `k` is not evaluated. Please see my (downvoted) answer for a clarification. :)

Comment: @SouravGosh I do address that in the bottom of the question, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @SouravGosh I see, will try to rectify.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I;m just trying to improve your answer. For some _unknown_ reason, mine got downvoted, so probably I'll remove mine. :)

Comment: @SouravGosh Don't worry, I wrote something wrong, (funnily enough got upvotes), you corrected me -> fine.

Answer (score 2):

In your code,

```
 w=i||j||k;
```

is equivalent to

```
w= ((i||j) || k);
```

That means, first the `(i||j)` will be evaluated, and based on the result (if 0), the later part will be evaluated.

So, in your case, `i` being `4`, `(i||j)` evaluates to `1` and based on the logical OR operator semantics, the later part is not evaluated and the whole expression yields `1` which is finally assigned to `w`.

Related quotes, from `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.14, Logical OR operator

> The `||` operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it
>   yields 0. The result has type `int`.

then, regarding the evaluation of arguments,

> [...] If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is
>   not evaluated.

and regarding the *grouping*,

> [...] the `||` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation;

Comment: I did not downvote, but your answer has kind of a flaw: For `(i||j)`, `j` will not be evaluated if `i` yields _true_ already. You are basically right that this `||`-expression **will** be evaluated as such, but just not necessary both operands.

Comment: @Olaf Sir, I understand your point, but I never mentioned that `j` will get evaluated in the evaluation of `(i || j)`. The logical OR will get evaluated, no? Can you suggest any better wordings? FWIW, to avoid any confusion, I have already added the related quotes from the standard.

Comment: To me it was ok, because I know the details. With the addition it is fine now. I too have sometimes DVs without comment. Maybe there should be an requirement to leave a comment. How else should one improve one's answer?

Answer (score 0):

The result of boolean operators yields an `int` value of `0` or `1`.

See [6.5.13](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.13) and [6.5.14](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.14), paragraph 3.

*The [...] operator shall yield 1 [or] 0. The result has type int.*