# 'If' efficiency when evaluating 2 expressions

Tags: perl

```
if(expression1 or expression 2)
{
do something
}
```

If 'expression1' returns true, does the compiler starts to execute 'do something' or it evaluates the second expression too?

Answer (score 2):

No, `expression2` will **not** be evaluated if `expression1` is `true.`

This is because `or` is *short-circutted* in perl: once the result of the entire expression is known, evaluation stops. Evaluation occurs from left to right.

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast! :)

Comment: A 2 minute wait is an eternity on some tags ;-) It's true also in C, C++, and Java. The only language I can think of that **doesn't** do this is VBA.

Comment: This is true in many languages, and is often used as a feature. `./configure && make && make test && make install` for example :)

Comment: Or in Perl: `open(...) or die $!;`

Comment: @Bathsheba, Apparently, C++ **doesn't** short-circuit when the operators are overloaded ([ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/628554/589924)).

Comment: @ikegami: you're absolutely right. The reason is simple: the overloaded function takes two parameters and both parameters are evaluated before the function body is reached. I was asked this at interview once.