# Is order guaranteed in an or expression

Tags: c#, operator-precedence

I have an expression like this:

```
EqualByComparer comparer;
if (ListEqualByComparer.TryGetOrCreate(x, y, out comparer) ||
    EnumerableEqualByComparer.TryGetOrCreate(x, y, out comparer))
{
    return comparer.Equals(x, y, compareItem, settings, referencePairs);
}
```

Will `ListEqualByComparer.TryGetOrCreate` always be called before `EnumerableEqualByComparer.TryGetOrCreate`?

Comment: Yes and if it returns true, EnumerableEqualByComparer.TryGetOrCreate(x, y, out comparer) will not be called (short circuit evalution)

Comment: See also [Operator ||](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6373h346.aspx) - in `if (x || y)` it is guaranteed that `x` will be checked (first). If `x` is `true`, `y` will *not* be evaluated at all.

Comment: I believe so, this exact context being the reason for it. The code is compiled this way to save memory, as if the first condition is true, it will not have to evaluate the second condition

Comment: Sorry about the dupe, I did a search but failed.

Comment: Just to note, the fact the sequence is fixed and the second condition is only called if necessary is often both important and useful.  I often write conditions such as `if (foo == null || foo.bar())`

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse Indeed, i also use this when i get a collection to check if it is null or if it has any objects in int if ( collection == null || !collection.Any() )

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Will `ListEqualByComparer.TryGetOrCreate` always be called before `EnumerableEqualByComparer.TryGetOrCreate`?

Yes, and as `||` is short-circuiting, the second call will only be made if the first call returns `false`.

From the C# 5 specification, section 7.12.1:

> When the operands of `&&` or `||` are of type `bool`, or when the operands are of types that do not define an applicable `operator &` or `operator |`, but do define implicit conversions to `bool`, the operation is processed as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> The operation `x || y` is evaluated as `x ? true : y`. In other words, `x` is first evaluated and converted to type `bool`. Then, if `x` is true, the result of the operation is `true`. Otherwise, `y` is evaluated and converted to type `bool`, and this becomes the result of the operation.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to find it in the language spec but failed.

Comment: @JohanLarsson: Have added a spec reference.

Comment: A question: As these are function calls, does it mean that function calls are also called from left to right, one-by-one or could it be that all functions would be called in some order to extract the operands before evaluating them?

Comment: @Veksi: I'm not sure what you mean in this case. Evaluating the operand means calling the method here... you can't "evaluate the left operand" without calling the method, and the language is guaranteeing that the right operand won't be evaluated until the left operand is evaluated. Generally speaking the *does* guarantee left-to-right evaluation, but that would be more important for something like `Foo(Bar(), Baz())`

Comment: That was the question, I suppose. In C++ (I believe), if one has a conditioanl such as `if(func1() && func2() && func3()`, I believe it is implementation defined if all the functions will executed before evaluating the conditional in all the cases. That is, not just calling functions one-by-one from left to right. Link: http://cpptruths.blogspot.fi/2014/09/short-circuiting-overloaded-and-using.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order.

Comment: @Veksi: Well, that looks like it involves operator overloading as well. That's a slightly different matter. Note that the C# spec here is explicitly talking about situations where the operands are of type `bool`, or convertible to `bool` without also overloading `|` or `&`.

Comment: @Veksi C++ has the same rule as C# when dealing with the built in && / II, but it does *not* offer the same guarantee when `operator &&` is overloaded (which is why you are *strongly* recommended not to overload `operator &&`).  OTOH given `foo( bar(), baz() )`, I am pretty sure that C# guarantees `bar` will be called before `baz`, but C++ does not.

Comment: I guess it's worth noting that even though `Foo` is strictly left most it will still be called last.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - details are in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx).

The second condition is only evaluated if the first is false

Answer (score 4):

From C# Reference ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)):

> The conditional-OR operator (**||**) performs a logical-OR of its **bool** operands. If the first operand evaluates to **true**, the second operand isn't evaluated. If the first operand evaluates to **false**, the second operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to **true** or **false**.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the order is guaranteed. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx) states:

> Logical operators also guarantee evaluation of their operands from left to right. However, they evaluate the smallest number of operands needed to determine the result of the expression. This is called "short-circuit" evaluation. Thus, some operands of the expression may not be evaluated.