# How compilers evaluate control flow statements?

Tags: c, operators, evaluation, control-flow

I recently noticed that it's possible to verify the existence of a variable (**e.g** pointer type in C) and just after, verify an element inside of that variable (**e.g** dereferencing the pointer) in a same control flow (**e.g** if statement).

**Before noticing**

```c
if (my_array)
{
    if (my_array[n])
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

**After noticing**

```c
if (my_array
     && my_array[n])
{
    //Do something
}
```

I was a little bit suprised about that behaviour, and I used **valgrind** to see if the system has been "kind" with me during the execution of the program, but **valgrind** was straight and said that I've got

> ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts.

So I whish to know if the compiler only refers to operators, in order to create a sort of **flowchart**, or it's another type of evaluation. And does every compilers use the same type of behavior ?

Comment: Boolean operators are short circuiting and have defined order of evaluation in C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order

Comment: valgrind wouldn't help you detect a problem here, if there were one. Valgrind only detects what happens; not what could happen if undefined behaviour turned out differently.

Comment: Thanks to short-circuiting of logical operators (link by IljaEverilä) - which is guaranteed by the C standard - your two samples of code are functionally equivalent.   The only way for behaviour to be incorrect is for `n` to be a bad index with `my_array` - which your code does not check.