# How does this code produces an output of 6 and 3?

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment, and-operator

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
     int x = 0,y = 0,k = 0;
     for(k = 0; k < 5; k++){
         if(++x > 2 && ++y > 2)    x++;
     }
     printf("x = %d and y = %d",x,y);
}
```

I'm not able to understand how the above piece of code generates x = 6 and y = 3.

RESOLVED : I didn't know that when there is &&, if the first statement evaluates to false the second will not be executed.

Comment: What don't you understand about it? The increments? The if statement? What?

Comment: Use a debugger or `printf`to see the value of each variable for each iteration. It shall help you understand how it works step by step

Comment: print k, x, & y within the loop and see whats going on

Comment: Whoever CVed as dup: It is not!

Comment: I retracted my vote.....don't know why it wasn't. I voted to reopen

Comment: I re-opened the post. Although... possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-logical-operators-mandated-and-evaluation-order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&&` is a *short-circuit* operator.

The first time through the loop, only `++x` is evaluated.
The second time through the loop, only `++x` is evaluated.
The third time through the loop, both are evaluated.
...

Answer (score 3):

Not related to your question, but please read [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c) `int`.

---

[c](/questions/tagged/c) enables **short circuit**, and `&&` is an operator that follows that. So, this:

```
if(++x > 2 && ++y > 2)
```

says:

1. Increment `x` by 1.
2. If `x` is greater than 2 (thus the first operand of `&&` is true),
   evaluate the second operand.
3. The second operand says to increment `y` by 1, and if `y > 2` is
   true, then the whole if condition will be true.

---

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
     int x = 0, y = 0, k = 0;
     for(k = 0; k < 5; k++){
         x = x + 1;
         if(x > 2)
         {
             y = y + 1;
             if(y > 2)
             {
                 x = x + 1;
             }
         }  
     }
     printf("x = %d and y = %d", x, y);
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is the short-circuit operator.

```
if ( ++x > 2 && ++y > 2 )
```

in this `if` statement the second operand will be evaluated only if the first one is true.

1. when `k=0` `X` will be incremented by `1`. Now `x` value is `1`. `x > 2` is false. So `Y` won't increase.
2. When `k=1` `X` will be incremented by `1` . Now `X` value is `2` . `X > 2` is false. So `Y` won't increase.
3. when `k=2` `X` will be incremented by `1` . Now `X` value is `3` . `X > 2` is true . So `Y` will be incremented by `1` . Now `Y` value is `1` . but `Y > 2` is false . So total if condition is `false`.
4. when `k=3` `X` will be incremented by `1` . Now `X` value is `4` . `X > 2` is true . So `Y` will be incremented by `1` . Now `Y` value is `2` . but `Y > 2` is false . So total if condition is `false`.
5. when `k=4` `X` will be incremented by `1` . Now `X` value is `5` . `X > 2` is true . So `Y` will be incremented by `1` . Now `Y` value is `3` .  `Y > 2` is true . So total if condition is `true`. Then `X` will be incremented by `1`.
6. The final answer is **X=6** and **Y=3** .

Comment: I don't like how this is worded: "the first operand is true then only the second operand will be evaluated." It looks like you are saying that the second operand will be evaluated and the first one won't. I'm not a native speaker, but I think you should change it to "only if the first operand is true will the second one be evaluated" to avoid the ambiguity (to any native speakers reading this, can you please let me know whether I am right?). Or, to keep it simple, I would rephrase it as "in this `if` statement the second operand will be evaluated only if the first one is true."

Answer (score -1):

```
if(++x > 2 && ++y > 2)
```

In this line if first condition is false it will not evalute second condition. So first condition is false until value of x is 3