# C++ difference between "and", "&&" and "bitand"

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I would like to know if there is any difference in speed or performance in C++ between:

AND operation: `&&, and, bitand`

OR operation: `||, or, bitor`

Or it's the same performance for all of them?

Comment: `&&` and `and` are aliases. `bitand` is an alias of `&`. And there is no difference between e.g. `&&` and `and`. None whatsoever.

Comment: Here you go: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative  Regarding performance: you need to measure it under your expected workload.

Comment: What would be the reason to know the difference in performance of operators that do different things?

Comment: also && represents rvalue references too in c++11

Comment: The use of `and`, `or`, etc is uncommon and therefore slightly confusing for many readers of the code. So it is recommended to use `&&` and `||`, unless you have an unusual keyboard where these are missing.

Comment: They do unrelated things. And if you're asking about speed, this kind of question is a bit like asking "How could I lose more weight, by getting a haircut or by trimming my fingernails?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because unless one is measuring specific use cases, the answer could be anything at all (an operation is faster or slower depending on how it is used).

Answer (score 4):

Before going into details, `&&` and `and` are equivalent, so are `&` and `bitand`, `||` and `or` as well as `|` and `bitor`. More details can be found on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative)

There definitely are differences between them, so let's look at them in more detail:

- `&&` and `||` are **logical operators**. Their result is either `true` or `false`, nothing else.
  If at least one of the operands (`||`) or both operands (`&&`) is not `false`, then the result is `true`, `false` otherwise.
- `&` and `|` are **bitwise operators**. They operate on every bit of the operands independently.
  This is mostly used for bit-twiddling operations on numbers like to set all but the lowermost 3 bits of a number to 0 (think about their binary representation):

  ```
  int result1 = number & 0b111;
  // or to set the 3 lowermost bits to 1
  int result2 = number | 0b111;
  ```

You might know that for conditional statements, every number in C++ can be interpreted as a boolean value, more specifically 0 is `false` and everything else is `true`. This can lead to some confusion, as the following example shows:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
if (a && b) {
    std::cout << "a && b\n";
}
if (a & b) {
    std::cout << "a & b\n";
}
```

This will output only `a && b` because `a & b` is 0 and thus `false`, even though `a` and `b` both are not `false`.

In short, use `&&` and `||` for logical operations, `&` and `|` for bitwise operations *on numbers*, but watch out for side-effects:

Apart from the different scopes of use, there is another difference between these operators, namely the mandatory **short-circuit evaluation** for logical operators (`&&` and `||`). This means that if we already know the result of the expression from evaluating the first operand, then the second operand **must not** be evaluated. This means that the following two pieces of code are equivalent:

```
    bool result = is_this_true() && is_that_true();
    // equivalent:
    bool result;
    if (is_this_true()) {
        result = is_that_true();
    } else {
        result = false;
    }
```

The same holds for the logical or operator:

```
    bool result = is_this_true() || is_that_true();
    // equivalent:
    bool result;
    if (is_this_true()) {
        result = true;
    } else {
        result = is_that_true();
    }
```

This is because

1. If one of the operands of `&&` is `false`, then the result is always `false`
2. If one of the operands of `||` is `true`, then the result is always `true`

This can definitely have an impact on the performance compared to the bitwise operators, basically in two different ways:

1. If the evaluation of `is_that_true()` takes a lot of time, then the short-circuit evaluation might save you time in the cases when the result gets short-circuited.
2. If the evaluation of both `is_this_true()` and `is_that_true()` are quite fast but have side-effects the compiler cannot get rid of, then the additional branch introduced by the equivalent `if` statement might have a small performance penalty involved (for more details, read up on branch misprediction). However, in most cases this performance difference is so tiny that you should never worry about it unless the evaluation of these logical operators is your performance bottleneck (which, again, should be very unlikely)

If you want to know more, there are already several answers detailing the effect of short circuit evaluation, see for example 
[Is short-circuiting logical operators mandated? And evaluation order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-logical-operators-mandated-and-evaluation-order)

Comment: Branch misprediction has a catastrophic effect. It can imply the loss of dozen cycles. Where performance truly matters (in innermost loops), branchless expressions can be advantageous.

Comment: I know, but I find it very unlikely that a logical operation is a) the bottleneck of an application and b) the second operand can be evaluated very quickly, but at the same time has a side-effect that prevents the compiler from using a branchless instruction instead of a branch. The question itself didn't seem to me to ask for too much technicality ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Or it's the same performance for all of them?

This is a bit of an apples/oranges question. `and` and `bitand` perform different jobs.

example:

```
bool both_nonzero(int x, int y)
{
    return x and y;
}

bool have_corresponding_bits(int x, int y)
{
    return bool(x bitand y);
}
```

corresponding assembler (gcc-x86_64 -O3):

```
both_nonzero(int, int):
        test    edi, edi
        setne   al
        test    esi, esi
        setne   dl
        and     eax, edx
        ret

have_corresponding_bits(int, int):
        test    edi, esi
        setne   al
        ret
```

As you can see, the second function requires fewer instructions, but from a CPU's point of view it's doing a simpler task (bitwise operations being the bread and butter of a CPU's life's work).