# C++ Boolean with Integers

Tags: c++, integer, boolean

OK so obviously this question might sound dumb for more experienced people, but, for the following lines the result I get is **0**:

```
int x = 2,
y = -2;

cout << (x++ - y && (--x + y));
```

I understand it means that either one of these two expressions equals 0, but how? As far as I understand, this should be (3 && -1)?

Also, a little subquestion: when does x++ exactly take effect? On the next occurance of x within the same expression, after the left-shift operator within the same line, or in the next statement?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like undefined behavior with the order that `x++` and `--x` will get executed.

Comment: UB for sure, but as an aside most coders would always do `((x++ - y) && (--x + y))` just to be unambiguous about the desired precedence behavior. Makes not difference here tho

Comment: Did you read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) already what [not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)?

Comment: I don't believe this is UB. The left part of `operator&&` is necessarily evaluated completely, including all side effects, before the right side. This is because `operator&&` is short circuited for fundamental arithmetic types. This doesn't seem to be a "`i++ + ++i`" question.

Comment: After you've evaluated the left part, `x == 3`. So when you evaluated the right part, `--x + y` is `2 + (-2)` which is `0`. I get `4 && 0`.

Comment: If you aren't on it already @FrançoisAndrieux please write up an answer. The comments above suggest this deserves formal treatment, notice, and some staying power.

Comment: If you ever write such code, you will be damned to eternity in hell debugging COBOL programs.

Answer (score 4):

> As far as I understand, this should be (3 && -1)?

you understand wrong:

first left side is fully evaluated, as it is necessary for short circuit evaluation with logical `and` (details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-logical-operators-mandated-and-evaluation-order))

```
x++ - y == 4 // as result of x++ == 2 so (2-(-2)), after that x == 3
```

result is `true` so right side is evaluated:

```
--x + y ==  0 // as result of --x == 2 so (2+(-2)), after that x == 2
```

result on the right is `false` so result of `and` is `false` as well which printed by `std::ostream` as `0`

Note: short circuit evaluation of logical `or` and `and` operations make such code valid (making them sequenced) but you better avoid such questionable expressions. For example simple replacing logical `and` to binary would make it UB.

Comment: You should mention that the `&&` short-circuits, so it forces the LHS and RHS to be evaluated sequentially. With an operator that doesn't short-circuit, evaluating `x++` and `++x` within the same expression can result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson sure, implicitly I mentioned that by ("result is true so right side is evaluated"), but it would not harm to mention that explicitly.

Comment: @Slava `after that x == 2`  is incorrectly placed (even though it's CORRECT)

Comment: @MohammadKanan why so?

Comment: @Slava precisely:  `--x + y ==  0  after that x == 2,  (2 + (-2))`

Comment: @MohammadKanan your variant can be confusing even more, the thing is you cannot say when `x` becomes 2 until operations sequenced, that the reason for UB. You only know that `x` would be 2 after expression ends  and result of `--x` is 2 as well. The same for the first, x == 3 after that and result of `x++` is 2. It is wrong way to look on result of expressions `--x` or `x++` as current value of x.

Comment: @Slava,  as --x gets evaluated first , yes its confusing in any place

Comment: @MohammadKanan changed it, it should be clear now I think

Comment: @Slava agree now

Comment: I understand now. I was actually also suspicious, if x++ changes the value after the statement, or after the &&. But I guess it happens after &&.