# Is there ordering with c++ && (AND) operator

Tags: c++

`a` - checks whether input is defined for function `b`

```
if (a) {
    if (b) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

clearly works.
Does the `&&`-operator always check the first input?

```
if (a && b) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Would this possibly cause undefined behaviour from b function?

Comment: Read the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/628554/469210

Comment: For future reference the term is called "short-circuit evaluation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the expression `a && b`, assuming `&&` is the built-in operator and not an overloaded one, `b` is **only** evaluated if `a` evaluates to `true`.

That's why you can write things like `if (a != nullptr && *a)`.

We call this *short circuiting*. `||` also has the property.

Comment: does same hold for || operator? Also, source?

Comment: @BorticFan: Ha, just put that in for personal pleasure. Source is the C++ standard innit.

Comment: @BorticFan Your C++ book explains it, and the dupe contains a verbatim quote from the standard

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the built-in `&&` short-circuits.

So, if `a` is false, `b` will not be evaluated. This is guaranteed, unless there is an overload of `operator&&(type of a, type of b)`.

Comment: Very very good point on the overload!

Answer (score 0):

As Bathsheba said, if your code is

```
if (a && b) {
    //...
}
```

Then b will only be checked if a results to true.
This is because the && operator is a so-called shortcut operator.
The same goes for the logical OR (||).

```
if (a || b)//...
```

In this case, however, b would only be evaluated if a results to false.

These are not to be confused with the bitwise operators (& and |), which check both values regardless.

Comment: Not sure I've ever heard it called a "shortcut operator". If anything, some people call `x += 42` a "shortcut operator" (versus `x = x + 42`) though even that doesn't seem to be widespread.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Shortcircuit operator. I typed the answer on my phone, I guess autocorrect got me there.