# Logoical operators in return

Tags: c, return, logical-operators

I have a function in a program that should return an int, but the return looks like this:

```
return wordlength > 6.0 &&  wordlength< 9.0
       && strcasestr (string, "substring1") && strcasestr (string, "substring2")
       && strcasestr (string, "substring2") && strcasestr (string, "substring4")
```

The wordlength is a double that contains the average length of the words in the string.

My question is what does the return statement actually return?

Comment: What do you think the `&&` operator returns?

Comment: It returns an `int` that tells you if all those conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Welcome to SO!... It will return a boolean value. Easiest way to check is by looking at the function headline `return_type FUNCTION_NAME(arguments_list)`.

Comment: A ture or false value. But the function is int so shouldn't it return int?

Comment: @tocsika7 of what type are true and false values in C?

Comment: On most CPUs boolean values are mapped on an integer type... 0b00000001 = "True" and 0b00000000 = "False"

Comment: in C true is just 1 and false is just 0. there aren't even true/false keywords in C. to be more precise, false is 0 and true is any non zero integer. but conditions returns 1/0

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator precedence rules say that relational operators like `<` take precedence over `&&`. Therefore the sub-expression `wordlength > 6.0 &&  wordlength< 9.0` is equivalent to `(wordlength > 6.0) && (wordlength< 9.0)`.

Once that's sorted out, note that `&&` has left-to-right *associativity*. Meaning that in case there are several of the same operator with the same precedence in the same expression, like for example `a && b && c`, then it is equivalent to `(a && b) && c`.

The logical operators like `&&` has a "short-circuit" order of evaluation. Meaning that in `0 && b`, only the operand `0` is evaluated/executed. See [Is short-circuiting logical operators mandated? And evaluation order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-logical-operators-mandated-and-evaluation-order)

And finally, logically expressions in C do not yield a boolean type (like in C++) but an `int` of value `1` or `0`. Even though the type is `int`, this can be regarded as if it is of type `bool` though, and you can safely write code such as `bool b = x && y;`.

Comment: You example you gave would be correct with `||` instead of `&&`, or with `0` instead of `1` but in this case both operands needs to be evaluated.

Comment: @AsafRosemarin Yep typo, fixed.