# Do logical operators affect each other in a if statement?

Tags: c++, logical-operators

I have 4 statements, I only want to check statement 2-4 if statement 1 is true
the following is the pseudo code of what I am trying to achieve

```
if (statement 1) {
  if (statement 2 or statement 3 or statement 4){
    do something()
  }
}
```

I was wondering whether the following code will do the same

```
if(s1 && s2 || s3 || s4) {
  doSomething();
}
```

or if I have to do it like

```
if (s1) {
  if (s2 || s3 || s4) {
     doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: Be careful with operator precedence. `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so you want  `if(s1 && (s2 || s3 || s4))`.

Comment: `s1 && s2 || s3 || s4`, due to rules of operator precedence, is equivalent to `(s1 && s2) || s3 || s4`, not to `s1 && (s2 || s3 || s4)`.    Your second lot of code tests the latter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

```
if(s1 && s2 || s3 || s4)
```

is the same as

```
if((s1 && s2) || s3 || s4)
```

since `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`.  What you want is

```
if(s1 && (s2 || s3 || s4))
```

which will only be true if `s1` is true and any of `s2`, `s3`, and `s4` are true.

You are also [guaranteed to have short circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-logical-operators-mandated-and-evaluation-order) on `&&` as long as that is a built in operator and that means that if `s1` is false, `s2`, `s3`, and `s4` will not be evaluated.  This also happens wth `||` for built in operators and as soon as you hit a true expression the rest won't be evaluated as true or anything is true.

Comment: @bolov I've added that.

Comment: One more important thing. In `if (a && b)` if `a` is falve, `b` is guaranteed not to be evaluated (the same is true for `if (a || b)`, i.e. if `a` is true, `b` wont be evaluated). This is typically used in statements like `if (p_node && p_node->something)`.

Comment: so for example ```if (mode = 0 (acc.balance < 0 || acc.balance < change)) return 0;```?

Comment: @ArielHurdle `if (mode == 0 && (acc.balance < 0 || acc.balance < change)) return 0;`

Comment: @NathanOliver ah yes, typo on my behalf there :) and thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @ArielHurdle No problem.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the logical operators `&&` and `||` are short-circuiting - this means that the left operand of the operator is going to be evaluated first, and if the result won't be affected by doing further evaluations then it'll stop there. For example, `x() && y()` will indeed only evaluate `y()` if `x()` was true, and `x() || y()` will only evaluate `y()` if `x()` was false.

As a recommendation, you should take care to put parentheses around things to make it more clear which order of operations you intended though:

```
s1 && (s2 || s3 || s4)
```

rather than

```
s1 && s2 || s3 || s4
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put parenthesis on your `||` statements. So:

```
if(s1 && (s2 || s3 || s4)) { // << note the parenthesis
  doSomething();
}
```

is equivalent with

```
if (s1) {
  if (s2 || s3 || s4) {
     doSomething();
  }
}
```

This works because of **Short-circuit evaluation**. Basically if s1 is false, the parenthesis won't be evaluated. You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).