# Expected no change in variable but unary operator works even in false if statement. Why so?

Tags: c, if-statement, unary-operator

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int y=15;
    if(y++>19 && y++!=21 && y++>21)
    printf("%d",y);
    else
    printf("%d",y);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected output to be 15 or even 18 but it gives out 16 and I don't know why.

Comment: Are you aware of the [short circuiting behavior of &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-logical-operators-mandated-and-evaluation-order)?

Comment: 15 (rather than 16, because of postfix increment) is less than 19, not greater, so thanks to short-circuit evaluation the other operands don't need to be evaluated. You're still incrementing `y`, though, exactly one time - so `y` will be `16`.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things are going on in the line

```
if(y++>19 && y++!=21 && y++>21)
```

The `&&` operator (along with the `||`, `?:`, and comma operators) forces left-to-right evaluation, meaning that `y++ > 19` is evaluated before `y++ != 21`, which will be evaluated before `y++ > 21`. It also introduces a *sequence point*, so all side effects of `y++ > 19` will be applied before `y++ != 21` is evaluated.

The `&&` operator *short-circuits* - `y++ != 21` will only be evaluated if `y++ > 19` evaluates to non-zero (`true`), and `y++ > 21` will only be evaluated if both prior expressions evaluate to non-zero.

The postfix `++` operator yields the current value of the operand (so `y++` evaluates to `15`); as a *side effect*, it increments the operand, so after `y++ > 19` is evaluated, `y` is incremented to `16`, even though the overall expression evaluates to `false` (`0`).

Answer (score 3):

Here y++>19 ==> y is compared against 19 and then incremented due to postfix ++.
So, y++>19 is actually evaluated as 15>19 and then y gets incremented and becomes 16.

Since 15>19 is false, the rest of the condition y++!=21 && y++>21 is not evaluated and control goes to else condition and prints y.  Since y already became 16 above, it prints 16.

Note that in short-circuit evaluation, A && B && C, if A gets evaluated to true then only B gets evaluated.
If both A and B gets evaluated to true then only C gets evaluated.

Thus, in your case, since A is false, there was no further evaluation of B and C and the control just enters else part of it and prints y.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to read about *operator precedences* (and while at it *associativity*). Usually each language has a specification that explains the functionings, so does C. Sources online are abound, a great book for learning C is K&R, well explained and interesting exercices.

I'll walk you through this example:

```
int y=15; // y is assigned the value 15, the return of the assignment is discarded (you will encounter that fact sooner or later surely)
```

The if statement can be described as `(y++>19) && (y++!=21) && (y++>21)` to make it clear. The `&&` operator is short-circuited: i.e. as soon as the final result can be determined, the rest will not be evaluated. Concretely in this case, as soon as a `false` or `0` is seen it stops evaluating and return `false`.

`y++>19` has two operators, postfix increment (higher precedence) and *greater than* (lower precedence). The postfix increment returns the value first, and then increments it, so effectively 15>19 is evaluated and `y` is incremented to `16`. Now remember the short-circuit. The program stops evaluating that expression since the final result will not change. The program enters the else part and prints the value assigned to `y` which is `16`.

Comment: Right @Ely he needs to properly learn assignment and logical operators before writing such statements since: false AND true results directly in a boolean false.

Answer (score 0):

here is what you wrote but just a little bit `shorter and faster`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int y = 15;
    y++;    // y = y + 1; means value of variable y equals 16 at this point
    if(y != 21 && y > 19)  // now you check this 16 != 21 && 16 > 19 which is false 
    printf("%d", y);
    else   // continue here directly 
    printf("%d", y);  // print value of variable y
    return 0;   // exit success
}
```

Yes, the result is always **16**. If this is not what you expected, then make sure you correct your first statement `if(y != 21 && y > 19)` .

I hope, this will help you correct your IF-statement (my suggestion).

I can recommend you these following two videos to properly understand **assignments, logical and comparison operators** before writing such statements since:

```
false AND true -> false
true AND false -> false
```

(1) **ArithmeticOperator Program** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oaO2eT46Mm8

(2) **ComparisonOperator Program** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovKVOj3xNsA

(3) **LogicalOperator Program** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kclf0PQnxrI

**Upvote** the answer after correction done.