# I was practicing decision control in c and i encountered a problem with logical operators

Tags: c, logical-operators

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i=4, j=-1, k=0, w, x, y, z;
   w = i||j||k;
   x = i&&j&&k;
   y = i||j&&k;
   z = i&&j||k;

   printf("w = %d, x = %d, y = %d, z = %d", w,x,y,z);
   return 0;
}
```

I was solving problems regarding C decision control with logical operators and I encountered a problem which I just cannot understand as the output was not something that I was expecting.

The output is:

```
w = 1, x = 0, y = 1, z = 1
```

Comment: Please, post code rather than images, what do you want to achieve and what is your issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically post all your code, error messages etc. as copy-pasted text, **not** images/links.

Comment: Also please mention what did you actually expect and why.

Comment: @DurYodhan Snipes What you need is to read at last the description of the logical operators || and &&.

Comment: Remember that `&&` takes [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170) over `||`. So `y = i || j && k;` is `y = i || (j && k);` These are boolean operations: a zero value is `false` and all other values are `true`.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for explaining that to me but I'm still confused like i mean i know what boolean is and zero = false and nonzero = true but  ( int i=4, j=-1, k=0, w, x, y, z;
   w = i||j||k;) here why is w = 1;

Comment: All `||` means if any of the expressions in between is `!= 0` then the result is true

Comment: `true || true || false` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @PeterKrebs ok I get it now so like WeatherVane said these are Boolean operations so the variables w, x, y, z store values as true and false in form of 1 and 0. Thanks for the help I was so confused

Comment: @WeatherVane i understand now dude it was storing boolean values in variables, thanks for the help I was super confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
w = i||j||k;
x = i&&j&&k;
y = i||j&&k;
z = i&&j||k;
```

is equivalent to:

```
w = ((i != 0) || (j != 0)) || (k != 0);

x = ((i != 0) && (j != 0)) && (k != 0);

y = (i != 0) || ((j != 0) && (k != 0));

z = ((i != 0) && (j != 0)) || (k != 0);
```

---

Some things to note:

1. The value 0 represents
   `false`.
2. Any value different from
   0 represents logical
   `true`.
3. Logical operators returns
   either `true` or `false`.
4. Operators that have the same
   precedence are bound to their
   arguments in the direction of
   their associativity.¹

   The associativity of `&&` is
   from left-to-right. So this
   statement:

   ```
   x = i&&j&&k;
   ```

   is parsed as:

   ```
   x = ((i != 0) && (j != 0)) && (k != 0);
   ```
5. Remember that && takes precedence
   over `||`. So

   ```
   y = i || j && k;
   ```

   is parsed as:

   ```
   y = i || (j && k);
   ```

   — @Weather Vane
6. The logical-AND operator has
   type
   int and the value 1 if both lhs
   and rhs compare unequal to zero.
   It has the value ​0​ otherwise (if
   either lhs or rhs or both compare
   equal to zero).

   There is a sequence point after
   the evaluation of lhs. If the
   result of lhs compares equal to
   zero, then rhs is not evaluated at
   all (so-called short-circuit
   evaluation).²
7. The logical-OR operator has type
   int and the value 1 if either lhs
   or rhs compare unequal to zero. It
   has value ​0​ otherwise (if both lhs
   and rhs compare equal to zero).

   There is a sequence point after
   the evaluation of lhs. If the
   result of lhs compares unequal to
   zero, then rhs is not evaluated at
   all (so-called short-circuit
   evaluation).³

[1] - [2] - [3] — cppreference.com

Comment: thanks a lot dude I understand now I was just confused from the output but now i know why it was giving 1 and 0 as out puts

Comment: i did but says it needs 15 votes

Answer (score 4):

There's a few things you need to know here:

- Any expression in C that has the value `0` is regarded as false, and any other expression with any other value different than zero is regarded as true.
- The result of boolean logical operators like `&&`, `||`, `==` etc is always `0` (false) or `1` (true).
- Operator precedence specifies how these expressions are parsed: that is, which operand belongs to which operator. For example in case of `y = i||j&&k;`, the operator precedence is `&&` (highest) then `||` then `=` (lowest). Therefore that expression is equivalent to:

  `y = ( i || (j&&k) );`
- The logical AND `&&` and OR `||` operators are some of the few operators in C that have a well-defined order of evaluation. They are guaranteed to be executed from left to right. They are guaranteed to stop evaluation in case only the left operand is all that's needed to tell if the expression will become true or false.

  That's a common beginner FAQ, read all about it here: [Is short-circuiting logical operators mandated? And evaluation order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-logical-operators-mandated-and-evaluation-order)

  For the previous example `y = ( i || (j&&k) );`, `i` is the left-most operand of `||` which is what matters. It is `4`, therefore true. `true || anything` is always true, so the rest of the expression is not evaluated.

Comment: thanks, for taking ur time to answer my problem i understand now the variables were storing boolean values in them as true and false (1 and 0), i was super confused