# Logical Operations not as expected in C

Tags: c, logical-operators

Can someone explain how the following code functions

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int a = 2, b = -1, c = 0, d;
    d = a-- || b++ && c++;
    printf("%d%d%d%d", a, b, c, d);
}
```

I was expecting the value to be `1010` since I have read that `&&` has more priority than `||`, hence it should be evaluated first. But the answer seems to be `1-101`. Could someone explain why? I know about the short circuit evaluation rule, but just don't understand why `b++ && c++` isn't performed first?

Comment: Short-circuit evaluation: the right part will be evaluated **only** if the first is false (0).

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-logical-operators-mandated-and-evaluation-order

Comment: Suppose `b++ && c++` were evaluated first. You evaluate `b++`. If it is false, you stop evaluating `b++ && c++` due to the nature of `&&`. If it is true, you evaluate `c++`. Then, either way, you know the result of `b++ && c++`. So you have evaluated `b++ && c++` first. But you know `||` is supposed to evaluate its left operand first. So how could that work? For `||` to evaluate its left operand first, it must evaluate its left operand first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operator precedence dictates how operands are grouped, not how they are evaluated.

Since `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, this:

```
d = a-- || b++ && c++;
```

Is the same as this:

```
d = (a--) || ((b++) && (c++));
```

Now looking at this, we can see that the left operand of `||` is `a--` and the right operand is `b++ && c++`.  So `a--` is evaluated first, and since the value of `a` is 2 this expression evaluates to 2.  This makes the left side of `||` true, meaning that the right side, i.e. `b++ && c++`, is not evaluated.  So because the left operand of `||` is nonzero, the result of the `||` operator 1.

So `a` is decremented to 1, `d` is assigned 1 because since that is the result of the `||` operator, and `b` and `c` are unchanged.

Comment: So it's the same as d = (a--) || (b++ && c++); ?

Comment: @Aevo Correct, as shown above.

Comment: You might want to clarify that the result of the `||` operator is `1` because one of its operands is non zero, not because the left operand happens to decrement `a` to the value `1`.  This coincidence might cause some confusion.