c++: Is (a || b) || c; equivalent to if (!a && !b) { c; }
I'm updating somebody else's code.
They did the following :
bool a();
bool b();

a() || b() || std::clog << "whine about something" << std::endl;

I'm replacing the std::clog bit with a void function and the compiler doesn't like that because it can't convert void to bool.
So... I decided to go with:
if (!a() && !b()) {
 c(); // Replacement to the clog bit.
}

Would this behave the same?
Note: This code was originally likely written in c++03 or c++11, but we're using c++17 now, in the unlikely case that makes a difference.

a and b are functions?

Yeah they're functions.

Sorry, just saw that I'd forgotten to actually call the functions in my example. Fixed it now. And c should also be a function. ADHD is hitting hard today.

static_cast<void>(a() || b() || c()); is equivalent to if (!a() && !b() { c(); }

Even if I prefer the if version, another way of rewrite a() || b() || (c(), true);.

They're equivalent according to de Morgan's Laws.

you should write unit tests. De Morgan's Law wont protect you from making a typo ;)

We have unit tests, but not for this. It's really a very trivial part of the code, logging a specific warning (hence why the original code uses std::clog)

true || false is true.  !true && !false is false.  So no, they are not the same.

Why overcomplicate it? You can rewrite X || Y as if (!X) { (bool)Y; } - this is a trivial syntactic change, which requires no reasoning about semantics (e.g. by appling de Morgan's laws).

@Barmar Nope, there's a common typo when people apply de Morgan's, and it's present here.

@DrewDormann The logical value isn't important here, just the short-circuiting behavior.

@Yksisarvinen Then you should post an answer explaining why they're not equivalent, and how to do it correctly.

I'm replacing the std::clog bit with a void function... Can you replace the std::clog bit with a bool function instead?  (Even though I'm not a fan of the a() || b() || c(); short-circuiting idiom use in C++.  I do use that pattern in languages where it is idiomatic in those languages.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws

This question is similar to: De Morgan's rules explained. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

That dupe target answers the "are they equivalent" part. For the short circuiting part, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/628526

@Eljay not really. IMO it doesn't make sense for a log function to return a bool. In fact, it's pretty nasty that clog is being used here in this way; I might have it wrong but I think this was implicitly converting std::ostream to bool?

"it doesn't make sense for a log function to return a bool" thats one way to see it. The other is that misusing shortcuirciting of || and && for control flow is bad style to begin with. If you just dont do that, there is no issue of a function not returning a bool. Though, I understand it wasnt your code ...

The std::ostream has an explicit conversion to bool.  The value reflects the state of the object: true means the stream is in a good state, false means that the stream is in a fail state.  The way the code is using the stream (in that idiosyncratic a() || b() || c << msg way, which is idiomatic in some other programming languages), that stream state is just dropped on the floor.

The equivalence of the two expressions values is covered by De Morgan's Law. To make sure short-cuirciting behavior is correct with regard to evaluating b() consider that if a() is true then b() will not be evaluated. This is the case for the two alternatives as you can convince yourself by examining the 4 possible cases:
#include<iostream>

template <bool s>
bool ab(bool x) {
    std::cout << (s?"a":"b") ;return x;
}
auto a = &ab<true>;
auto b = &ab<false>;
bool c() {
    std::cout << "c";
    return true;
}



void original(bool aa,bool bb) {
    a(aa) || b(bb) || c();
}
void alternative(bool aa,bool bb) {
    if (!a(aa) && !b(bb)) c();
}

void test(auto f) {
    f(true,true);
    std::cout << "\n";
    f(true,false);
    std::cout << "\n";
    f(false,true);
    std::cout << "\n";
    f(false,false);
    std::cout << "\n";
}


int main() {
    test(original);
    std::cout << "---\n";
    test(alternative);
}

Output:
a
a
ab
abc
---
a
a
ab
abc


I guess sacrificing some rep is still worth it if I get a good answer!
